# "Multiply" two strings

Tags: code-golf, string

<sub>This was inspired by a function I recently added to my language [Add++](https://github.com/SatansSon/AddPlusPlus). Therefore I will submit an  short answer in Add++ but I won't accept it if it wins (it wouldn't be fair)</sub>

Don't you hate it when you can multiply numbers but not strings? So you should correct that, right?

You are to write a function or full program that takes two non-empty strings as input and output their multiplied version.

How do you multiply strings? I'll tell you!

To multiply two strings, you take two strings and compare each character. The character with the highest code point is then added to the output. If they are equal, simply add the character to the output.

Strings are not guaranteed to be equal in length. If the lengths are different, the length of the final string is the length of the shortest string. The input will always be lowercase and may contain any character in the printable ASCII range (`0x20 - 0x7E`), excluding uppercase letters.

You may output in any reasonable format, such as string, list etc. Be sensible, integers aren't a sensible way to output in this challenge.

With inputs of `hello,` and `world!`, this is how it works

```
hello,
world!

w > h so "w" is added ("w")
o > e so "o" is added ("wo")
r > l so "r" is added ("wor")
l = l so "l" is added ("worl")
d < o so "o" is added ("worlo")
! < , so "," is added ("worlo,")
```

So the final output for `hello,` and `world!` would be `worlo,`.

## More test cases

(without steps)

```
input1
input2 => output

programming puzzles & code golf!?
not yet graduated, needs a rehaul => prtgyetmirgduuzzlesneedsde rolful

king
object => oing

blended
bold => boln

lab0ur win.
the "super bowl" => the0usuwir.

donald j.
trumfefe! => trumlefj.
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins! Luok!

Comment: This is the elementwise maximum of the strings, right? That doesn't seem anything like multiplying.

Comment: Nitpick: PPCG has graduated, we just didn't get a new design yet.

Comment: Possible relevant: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/74809/merging-two-strings/123187#123187

Comment: The first test case is wrong. It should be `"input1","input2" => "input2"`.

Comment: @a'_' That‘s not a test case; it’s a Demonstration of the Format of the other test cases

Answer (score 55):

### Haskell, 11 bytes

```
zipWith max
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcxLDgIhEEXRuat4EuPILXRchuOyKT42v0CR2GweGTu/9zhqB4cwp9mGLy8vDpG@M5JP2KDzBUCpPgluMFClZlspRp8sSh8jcMMde9YMm4O5PhVUyoKTBSvUnYT1A4lZNxAqO@pB/aHH0taX3x/eRc0f)

Nothing much to explain.

Comment: And I thought Mathematica had strange built-ins

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Mathematica has zipWith, it's called MapThread

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder actually, `zipWith` isn't too strange.  It's a fairly common  functional primitive.  The idea of "zipping" two lists together comes up in _many_ problems, and once you do that, you often want to apply some function to the resulting 2-element items, hence the "with" part.

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
øΣà?
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8I5ziw8vsP//v6AoP70oMTc3My9doaC0qiontVhBTSE5PyVVIT0/J03Rnisvv0ShMrVEAagspTSxJDVFRyEvNTWlWCFRoSg1I7E0BwA)

Comment: I feel like `ø€à` should work, but it don't.

Comment: Looks more like a question than an answer lol

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn `ø€à` does work now (in the legacy version of 05AB1E), but the output will be a list of characters instead of a string: [try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8I5HTWsOL/jv9b@gKD@9KDE3NzMvXaGgtKoqJ7VYQU0hOT8lVSE9PydN0Z4rL79EoTK1RAGoLKU0sSQ1RUchLzU1pVghUaEoNSOxNAcA).

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 16 bytes

```
ñl g îUy ®¬ñ oÃq
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=8WwgZyDuVXkgrqzxIG/DcQ==&input=WyJraW5nIiAib2JqZWN0Il0=) Takes input as an array of two strings.

Lack of min and max built-ins hurt Japt here, but it still manages to pull off a somewhat decent score...

#### Explanation

```
 ñl g îUy ®   ¬ ñ oÃ q
Uñl g îUy mZ{Zq ñ o} q
                        // Implicit: U = input array     ["object", "king"]
       Uy               // Transpose the strings of U.   ["ok", "bi", "jn", "eg", "c ", "t "]
          mZ{      }    // Map each string Z to
             Zq ñ o     //   the larger of the two chars. (Literally Z.split().sort().pop())
                        //                               ["o", "i", "n", "g", "c", "t"]
                     q  // Join into a single string.    "oingct"
Uñl g                   // Sort the two input strings by length and take the shorter.
      î                 // Trim the previous result to this length.
                        //            "king"î"oingct" -> "oing"
                        // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Answer (score 7):

## PHP>=7.1, 52 Bytes

```php
for(;$t=min(~$argv[1][$i],~$argv[2][$i++]);)echo~$t;
```

[PHP Sandbox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c6373f01fe411441e74865d25e7600b8aef6e259)

## PHP>=7.1, 69 Bytes

```php
for([,$a,$b]=$argv;(~$c=$a[$i])&&~$d=$b[$i++];)$r.=max($c,$d);;echo$r;
```

[PHP Sandbox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6c981e474956faddb84243a4d5565cfc9dd43b39)

## PHP>=7.1, 70 Bytes

```php
for([,$a,$b]=$argv;(~$c=$a[$i])&&~$d=$b[$i++];)$r.=$c>$d?$c:$d;echo$r;
```

[PHP Sandbox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/458e9e9ea8c8f858dea9b6b8f10c9cfff42e54a3)

Comment: Slightly golfed: `for(;$t=min(~$argv[1][$i],~$argv[2][$i++]);)echo~$t;`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
żœ-"«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY09EoIwEIV7TrFSSIM/N/AcDkORsAuCS8KEZBgovYKHsNAjWOl4ES8SzYjdm2@/fa8h5tH71/11XsWPq39eNu/Tbe99FkGW1KpzNklhDnkaYGd0ZUTb1qqCzk0TUw9LKDQSVJrLxS48KG1hJAtfE52whCkoIuxBgKGDcDyXHb8twdeyoeK/IJkUEgYuNeNMWcitMzDUah0u9kAQ964jA1IPHM8WaiUYofk5xrUllbRI8ij/AA)

#### How it works

```
żœ-"«  Main link. Arguemts: s, t (strings)

ż      Zipwith; form all pairs of corresponding characters from s and t.
       If one of the strings is longer than the other, its extra characters are 
       appended to the array of pairs.
    «  Dyadic minimum; get all minima of corresponding characters.
       This yields the characters themselves for unmatched characters.
 œ-"   Zipwith multiset subtraction; remove a single occurrence of the minimum from
       each character pair/singleton.
       This yields the maximum for pairs, but an empty string for singletons.
```

#### Example

Let **s = blended** and **t = bold**.

`ż` yields `["bb", "lo", "el", "nd", 'd', 'e', 'd']`. The last three elements are characters.

`«` is the vectorizing, dyadic minimum, so it yields `['b', 'l', 'e', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'd']`.

`œ-"` removes exactly one occurrence of the **n**<sup>th</sup> character in the second array from the **n**<sup>th</sup> string/character in the first array, yielding `["b", "o", "l", "n", "", "", ""]`. `œ-` is the *multiset subtraction* atom, and the quick `"` makes it vectorize.

When printed, this simply reads **boln**.

Comment: So, this is zipping, then taking the multiset difference of something, then there are some nice double quotes of misterious meaning, and finally the minimum. Nice... Explanation, please? :D

Comment: I've added a worked example.

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>47</s> 45 bytes

```js
f=
(a,b)=>a.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>c>b[i]?c:[b[i]])
```

```html
<div oninput=o.textContent=f(a.value,b.value)><input id=a><input id=b><pre id=o>
```

Conveniently `c>b[i]` returns false past the end of `b`. Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions.

Comment: Here in my cellphone that above code can not be executed. In the PC desktop the above examples I say can run ok, but not allow to change input for functions... Why not use Tio instead?

Comment: @RosLuP When the input is simple (2 stings in this case) I prefer to use a Stack Snippet that normally makes it easier to change the inputs and the output updates dynamically too.

Answer (score 7):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 8 bytes

```
/oI\
@m+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/18/3zOGyyFX@///pJzUvJTUFK6k/JwUAA)

#### Explanation

Alice also has this operator (which I called *superimpose*) but it doesn't limit the output to the shorter string's length (instead, the remaining characters of the longer string are appended). However, it also has an operator to truncate the longer of two strings to the length of the shorter one.

```
/   Reflect to SE, switch to Ordinal. The IP bounces diagonally up and down
    through the code.
m   Truncate, doesn't really do anything right now.
I   Read a line of input.
    The IP bounces off the bottom right corner and turns around.
I   Read another line of input.
m   Truncate the longer of the two input lines to the length of the shorter.
+   Superimpose: compute their elementwise maximum. 
o   Output the result.
@   Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 22 bytes

```
{[~] [Zmax] @_».comb}
```

As a bonus, it accepts any number of multiplicands, not just two.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
żḊ€ṁ@»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/9qZWxsef//xbzhuIrigqzhuYFAwrv///9sYWIwdXIgd2luLv90aGUgInN1cGVyIGJvd2wi)

Comment: `żṢ€Ḋ€` and `żṢ€ZṪ` both save a byte.

Comment: @Dennis very clever.

Answer (score 6):

## C, 58 bytes

```c
f(char*s,char*t){putchar(*s>*t?*s:*t);*++s&&*++t&&f(s,t);}
```

[**Try Online**](https://tio.run/##NYxLCsMgGIT3OcVfF0aNvUADzUW6EV8JGA0@KE3I2a0tZBYzwzB88m6lrNUQOYvIEv9HpsdW8q8Slp4sTyw92jiyYUgYN88YG5J4m866@AyrWDyh3dFBkyFo1s4Fjjh6h@jUDdHx4vUv39Px@m0x2CjWdfEWtrLvTifAIIPSYIMzt6khfMjw0RnaURWRteLgtVYJBEQ9i@IavTvrFw)

- -8 bytes @Steadybox

Comment: Darn, `f(s,t)char*s,*t;{` gives the same length.

Answer (score 6):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 28 bytes

```
{O^`
G`.
^.+$

M!\*`^.
Rm`^.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@/2j8ugcs9QY8rTk9bhYvLVzFGKyFOjysoF0j@/5@Uk5qXkprClZSfkwIA)

#### Explanation

```
{O^`
```

The `{` tells Retina to run the entire program in a loop until it fails to change the working string. `O` makes this a sorting stage which sorts non-empty lines by default. The `^` option reverses the result. So in effect, we get a reverse sort of the two lines if they're non-empty, putting the line with the larger leading character at the top.

```
G`.
```

Discard empty lines if there are any.

```
^.*$
```

If only one line is left, one of the lines was empty, and we remove the other one as well to stop the process.

```
M!\*`^.
```

Lots of configuration going on here. This matches (`M`) the first character in the working string (`^.`), returns it (`!`), prints it without a trailing linefeed (`\`) and then reverts the working string to its previous value (`*`). In other words, we simply print the first character of the working string (which is the maximal leading character) without actually changing the string.

```
Rm`^.
```

Finally, we remove the first character from each line, so that the next iteration processes the next character.

Comment: When you commented on my how tall are the monoliths answer, it occurred to me that my answer to this question was far too long, and that perhaps I was transposing inefficiently. After looking at how your transposition suggestion worked I decided that it wasn't appropriate for this question after all. I then came up with a new approach that saved me 19 bytes... and then scrolled down to find you'd already come up with a better version...

Comment: You can save 3 bytes since the ``G`.`` is unnecessary, although this does output an extra newline which you can remove by using `^.+¶$` or by prefixing a ``\`` to the start of the answer.

Comment: @Neil Oh good point. I could also use the latest commit (which isn't on TIO yet and probably isn't gonna be for a while) where I've made printing without trailing linefeeds the default (I could then also drop the other ``\``).

Answer (score 6):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
z▲
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/v@rRtE3///9XSspJzUtJTVECsvJzUpQA)

#### "Ungolfed"/Explained

Makes use of `zip f` that truncates the shorter list such that there are always two arguments for `f`, e.g. `zip f [1,2] [3,4,5] == zip f [1,2] [3,4] == [f 1 3, f 2 4]`:

```
z   -- zip the implicit lists A,B with  - e.g. "ab" "bcd" (lists of characters)
 ▲  -- maximum                          -      [max 'a' 'b', max 'b' 'c']
    -- implicitly print the result      -      "bc"
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>47</s> <s>44</s> 34 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to musicman523. -10 bytes thanks to Blender.*

Takes input as a list of strings.

```python
lambda a:''.join(map(max,zip(*a)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDRasMwDEXf8xVqH@ZkhDL2WCj7kK4MOZYTZ4plHJus@fksWccygUD43HuFFe6pE/@62Mv7wjhog4BnpU69OF8OGNb@qmcXymesqmpJNKaPBkca4QLXAta6qo6YpVY1qEkim4O61b/E@ZDTBh7D33uI0kYcBudbCHmeec17gkYMQStsD2@bx0uCOyVYlSZjIlODJzIjIETqMPOe97kGbRbRPTX/9mgmb8hsSAubHTDqlxxhcv60wdQRHMccKIKWiY@70IhHNtA/ZDEPliytPyxuRWElggPnYb/K@ccWovMJbOmq5Rs)

Answer (score 5):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>28, 24</s>, 21 bytes

```
Í./&ò
dd{JdêHPÎúúx
Íî
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3Cvnr7a4U1cKSnVXimHV3kEHO47vOvwrgquw72H1/3/n5Gak5NfBQRc5flFOSn2AA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: cd2e 2f26 f20a 6464 7b4a 64ea 4850 cefa  ../&..dd{Jd.HP..
00000010: fa78 0acd ee                             .x...
```

*Three bytes saved thanks to @nmjcman101!*

Explanation:

```
Í             " Globally substitute:
 .            "   Any character
  /           " With:
   &          "   That character
    ò         "   And a newline
dd            " Delete this line
  {           " Move to the first empty line
   J          " Delete this line
    dê        " Columnwise delete the second word
      HP      " Move to the first line, and paste the column we just deleted
        Î     " On every line:
         úú   "   Sort the line by ASCII value
           x  "   And delete the first character
Í             " Remove all:
 î            "   Newlines
```

Comment: Is the `dG` necessary?  Don't all of the newlines get removed with the `Íî` anyways?

Comment: @nmjcman101 It's needed in case the strings are different lengths.

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, 78 bytes

```
FromCharacterCode[Max/@Thread[#~Take~Min[Length/@x]&/@(x=ToCharacterCode@#)]]&
```

There is another answer in *Mathematica* already. This answer take input as a list of strings, so `/@` can be used on `#` instead of `{##}`. And we can just `Map` the long function name on object instead of assigning it to variables. (in fact, each Mathematica built-in symbol name is used at most once in the function)

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, <s>124</s> <s>120</s> <s>117</s> 63 bytes

```java
a->b->{for(int i=0;;i++)System.out.print(a[i]>b[i]?a[i]:b[i]);}
```

-4 bytes thanks to *@Khaled.K*.
-3 bytes thanks to *@Jakob*.

Inputs are two character-arrays, and it stops with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##bVLBbtswDL3nK1gdVht2jJ6b1cVQbNhlpx52SHKgLDpRKkuCTLVLg3x7JsceNhe7CE96jxQfyQO@4tJ5sgf1cmkM9j38QG1PC4CekXUDh6SoImtTtdE2rJ2tvk3gc7PHsN6W/9M8OdvHjsKkqWto4QEuuKzlsj61LmTaMuiHu9VKF0X@fOyZuspFrnxITIZrva1lOh4HdD@gfHW@rBapMh@lSZVNBb46raBLRWfPnEJ36y1gPhgAYOo5E9/JGFeKEsRPF4y6EfnqH1ZbH3kgRzDjfHC7gF2XsqZP398N9fAJGqcIds60N49DnHUMR2JIShWRSZVgiVQPCIH2GM0850tKNoQ5eaCGYU5KQ1aRGnjpjJqTBuVdDPCmbTUIeE@wEX30FEC6N7MRc7lyFo2CwygOsWuppcn8efF3wNf@XUPG/gGWMCH5p4/hOAKAtkLvzTHDit1TGu2XEPCY5XmFTUOeM/nhfazo3CA3@@zrr0GT1gMoP00jpxDGkRub3YrbAguxEYBWJXOikNdbz857Usk67xMFKcaFexAFpZ24fvBxf1Kyyej58hs)

```java
a->b->{                       // Method with two char-array parameters and no return-type
  for(int i=0;;i++)           //  Loop `i` from 0 up indefinitely (until an error is given)
    System.out.print(         //   Print:
      a[i]>b[i]?a[i]:b[i]);}  //    The character that has the highest unicode value
```

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript (ES2015), <strike>66</strike> <strike>63</strike> 49 bytes

```
a=>b=>[...a].map((c,i)=>c>b[i]?c:b[i]||'').join``
```

**Explanation:**

```
a=>b=>                       // Function with two string parameters
  [...a]                     // Split a into array of characters
    .map((c, i) =>           // Iterate over array
      c>b[i] ? c : b[i]||'') //   Use the character with the larger unicode value until the end of the larger string
    .join``                  // Join the array into a string
```

**Previous Versions:**

```
//ES2015
a=>b=>[...a].map((c,i)=>c>b[i]?c:b[i]).slice(0,b.length).join``    //63
a=>b=>a.split``.map((c,i)=>c>b[i]?c:b[i]).slice(0,b.length).join`` //66
a=>b=>a.split``.map((c,i)=>c>b[i]?c:b[i]).slice(0,Math.min(a.length,b.length)).join``   //85
a=>b=>{for(i=-1,c='';++i<Math.min(a.length,b.length);)c+=a[i]>b[i]?a[i]:b[i];return c}  //86
a=>b=>{for(i=-1,c='';++i<Math.min(a.length,b.length);)c+=a[d='charCodeAt'](i)>b[d](i)?a[i]:b[i];return c}   //105
a=>b=>a.split``.map((c,i)=>c[d='charCodeAt']()>b[d](i)?c:b[i]).slice(0,Math.min(a.length,b.length)).join``  //106

//With array comprehensions
a=>b=>[for(i of a.split``.map((c,i)=>c>b[i]?c:b[i]))i].slice(0,b.length).join``                             //79
a=>b=>[for(i of a.split``.map((c,i)=>c>b[i]?c:b[i]))i].slice(0,Math.min(a.length,b.length)).join``          //98
a=>b=>[for(i of ' '.repeat(Math.min(a.length,b.length)).split``.map((_,i)=>a[i]>b[i]?a[i]:b[i]))i].join``   //105
a=>b=>[for(i of Array.apply(0,Array(Math.min(a.length,b.length))).map((_,i)=>a[i]>b[i]?a[i]:b[i]))i].join`` //107
a=>b=>[for(i of a.split``.map((c,i)=>c[d='charCodeAt']()>b[d](i)?c:b[i]))i].slice(0,Math.min(a.length,b.length)).join``        //119
a=>b=>[for(i of ' '.repeat(Math.min(a.length,b.length)).split``.map((_,i)=>a[d='charCodeAt'](i)>b[d](i)?a[i]:b[i]))i].join``   //124
a=>b=>[for(i of Array.apply(0,Array(Math.min(a.length,b.length))).map((_,i)=>a[d='charCodeAt'](i)>b[d](i)?a[i]:b[i]))i].join`` //127
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first post!

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
otX>cwA)
```

Input is a cell array of strings, in the format `{'abcd' 'efg'}`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P78kwi653FHz//9q9aSc1LyU1BR1BfWk/JwU9VoA)

As an aside, this also works [for more than two strings](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P78kwi653FHz//9q9aSc1LyU1BR1BfWk/BwQlZiUXJeSmqZeCwA).

#### Explanation

Consider input `{'blended' 'bold'}`. The stack is shown upside down, with more recent elements below.

```
o    % Implicitly input a cell array of strongs. Convert to numeric
     % vector of code points. This right-pads with zeros if needed
     %   STACK: [98 108 101 110 100 101 100;
                 98 111 108 100   0   0   0]
tX>  % Duplicate. Maximum of each column
     %   STACK: [98 108 101 110 100 101 100;
                 98 111 108 100   0   0   0],
                [98 111 108 110 100 101 100]
c    % Convert to char
     %   STACK: [98 108 101 110 100 101 100;
                 98 111 108 100   0   0   0],
                'bolnded'
w    % Swap
     %   STACK: 'bolnded'
                [98 108 101 110 100 101 100;
                 98 111 108 100   0   0   0]
A    % All: gives true (shown as 1) for columns containing only nonzeros
     %   STACK: 'bolnded'
                [1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
)    % Use as logical index (mask). Implicitly display
     %   STACK: 'boln'
```

Answer (score 4):

## C#, <strike>81</strike> 78 bytes

```
a=>b=>{var s="";try{for(int q=0;;q++)s+=a[q]>b[q]?a[q]:b[q];}catch{}return s;}
```

C# has implicit `char` to `int` conversion (because a `char` is actually an `int` underneath) which is nice, and instead of looking for shortest string just try until failure

Comment: Beat me to it! However, save one byte with currying `a=>b=>` by compiling to a `Func<string, Func<string, string>>`. You can remove the braces around the for loop to save 2 bytes.

Comment: Side note: `C# has implicit char to int conversion` is true because a `char` is an `int` underneath.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder:  Not quite.  `sizeof(int) == 4` but `sizeof(char) == 2`.

Answer (score 4):

### R, 103 bytes

Code:

```
n=min(sapply(y<-strsplit(scan(,"",sep="\n"),""),length));cat(mapply(max,el(y)[1:n],y[[2]][1:n]),sep="")
```

Test cases:

```
> n=min(sapply(y<-strsplit(scan(,"",sep="\n"),""),length));cat(mapply(max,el(y)[1:n],y[[2]][1:n]),sep="")
1: programming puzzles & code golf!?
2: not yet graduated, needs a rehaul
3: 
Read 2 items
prtgretmirgduuzzlesneedsde rolful
> x <- scan(,"",sep=NULL)
1: asd asd 
3: 
Read 2 items
> n=min(sapply(y<-strsplit(scan(,"",sep="\n"),""),length));cat(mapply(max,el(y)[1:n],y[[2]][1:n]),sep="")
1: king
2: object
3: 
Read 2 items
oing
> n=min(sapply(y<-strsplit(scan(,"",sep="\n"),""),length));cat(mapply(max,el(y)[1:n],y[[2]][1:n]),sep="")
1: lab0ur win.
2: the "super bowl"
3: 
Read 2 items
the0usuwir.
```

Comment: Huh? Max works like that? TIL

Comment: [79 bytes!](https://tio.run/##FcrBCsIwDADQu18Re5AUKohHUfyQsUNcYzfo2tJkYP35Og/v9mqPy6tSbbiyztmL7RMplpU@yBHb/SxapcRFUSZK6Iyxf9a1YbiOox0ut3VJKFRKbNhc5BR0tnZ0wuWxz25KzaHSurcAZft@IwucYMqeIeT4Pj7NwaSs0Fhhj34jZe8gMXsBgsozbdH0Hw "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## Kotlin, <s>50</s> <s>41</s> 37 bytes

-9 bytes with function reference syntax
-4 bytes with extension function

```
fun String.x(o:String)=zip(o,::maxOf)
```

If s, and x are in scope, and not in a function, this method is only 16 bytes

```
s.zip(x,::maxOf)
```

[Demo](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/nubfa8m87ehb35729vbh64f439/jnj1je8dmgim992ti2c5dtakr4)

Comment: Here's a try.kotlinlang.org link: https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/ulm4nriigeio44jq1sdqer9sg2/spr3ucr6j9dr45e3od7nepsoie

Comment: You can use a lambda for 23 bytes: `{a,b->a.zip(b,::maxOf)}`

Answer (score 4):

## Excel, 86 bytes

```
=LET(x,SEQUENCE(MIN(LEN(A1),LEN(A2))),d,MID(A1,x,1),e,MID(A2,x,1),CONCAT(IF(d>e,d,e)))
```

Comment: ah, another actuary on code golf! Are you FSA or FCAS? I'm still working my way towards my ACAS. Also, I don't have the courage to golf in Excel.

Comment: I'm an ASA health actuary.  Excel will never be the shortest but it's an interesting challenge to get it to work on these problems.

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 12 bytes

```
q~z{1/~e>o}%
```

Input is a list of two strings. The program exits with an error (after producing the right output) if the two strings have different lengths.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7CuqtpQvy7VLr9W9f//aKXszLx0JQWl/KSs1OQSpVgA)

#### Explanation

```
q~              e# Read input and evaluate
  z             e# Zip: list of strings of length 2, or 1 if one string is shorter
   {      }%    e# Map this block over list
    1/          e# Split the string into array of (1 or 2) chars
      ~         e# Dump the chars onto the stack
       e>       e# Maximum of two chars. Error if there is only one char
         o      e# Output immediately, in case the program will error
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Add++](https://github.com/SatansSon/AddPlusPlus), 8 bytes

```
D,f,@@,^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ03HwUEn7r9Kmo69jj2XO5f///9KHqk5Ofk6Sv@VwvOLclIUlf7lF5Rk5ucV/9fVLUstKgYybQ30TAA)

In versions 0.4 through 1.11, `^` exponents two numbers or "multiplies" two strings, depending on the type of the arguments.

Comment: This is rather against the spirit of code-golf, to post a question knowing that your own language (that nobody else uses) has a built-in which gives it a monopoly. Thankfully, Jelly's conciseness wins again.

Comment: @FlipTack did you read the first line of the question? Even if this was 0 bytes, it wouldn't win.

Comment: @StephenS It seems that the feature inspired the challenge, not the other way round. The non-competing label is reserved for answers which use languages or features that were only implemented after the challenge.

Answer (score 3):

### Clojure, 31 bytes

```
#(map(comp last sort list)% %2)
```

Yay for function composition :) Returns a sequence of characters instead of a string, but they mostly work the same way in Clojure except when printing or regex matching.

Sadly `max` does not work with characters.

Comment: `max` doesn't work, but `max-key` does. `#(map(partial max-key int)% %2)` It's the exact same byte count, though.

Comment: Oh cool, I had forgotten about that. A lot simpler than for example `(ffirst (sort-by second ...)`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>55</s> 36 bytes

```
^
¶
{O`¶.*
}`¶.(.*)¶(.)
$2¶$1¶
1!`.*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/juvQNq5q/4RD2/S0uGpBlIaeluahbRp6mlwqRoe2qRgC5Q0VE/S0/v/PzsxL58pPykpNLgEA) Explanation: A line is prefixed to hold the result. While both strings still have characters left the inputs are sorted and the leading character with the highest code point is moved to the result while the other leading character is deleted. Finally the result is printed.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 47 bytes

```
f=([S,...s],[T,...t])=>S&&T?(S>T?S:T)+f(s,t):''
```

A recursive solution, which walks the string, always outputting the largest character.

**Snippet:**

```js
f=([S,...s],[T,...t])=>S&&T?(S>T?S:T)+f(s,t):''

console.log(f('programming puzzles & code golf!?','not yet graduated, needs a rehaul'));
console.log(f('king','object'));
console.log(f('blended','bold'));
console.log(f('lab0ur win.','the "super bowl"'));
console.log(f('donald j.','trumfefe!'));
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 29 bytes

```python
lambda*a:''.join(map(max,*a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDBasMwEETv/opNDrVjTCj0Fgj5kDSUlbWy5a61QpZwk5935abUFQjEvplZNP4ee3Fvizm/L4yj0ljjqSyPg1hXjejz/WpqPByWSFP8aHGiCc5wLSCfa9kTszRlA@UsgfWuvDW/xDqf4gqej7@5D9IFHEfrOvDp8eCc9wKtaIJO2Owuq8dJhDtFyEqdMJJuwBHpCRAC9Zh4y/vMQatF1EDtvz2KyWnSK1LCegOM6jUFmK07rjD2BPspeQqgZOb9JtTikDUMT1lIoyFD@YfFrSiMBLBgHWytnH5sPlgXK1PVNlf2DQ)

---

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 17 bytes

```python
''.join<..map$max
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBdTsMwEITfc4pthTCgKOIALRykVMixN4nTtdfyjwIVdw@2ikj9Ymu/mVl5FCt2Oa3D8WMVopvZuEPXWekfrPxaE8b0qWTECEc4NVDOSUxIxK1oQSwcSO/Euf0jxvmcKrg9/uc@8BiktcaN4PP1SiXvERRrhJFp2L1Xj@ME35igKHWWCXULDlFHkBBwkpm2vEsJqhbuZ1R3e3pCp1FX1DPpDZDsX3OAxbiuwjQh7GP2GKDnhfabULOTpGG@yUK2Aw5Yfticm@aujJ83qBU9@WBcglIYDHB4KReZmJ4rLq3GbHH9BQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 0.5](http://julialang.org/), 33 bytes

Pretty much the same concept as Python2, but shorter.

```julia
a->join(map(maximum,(zip(a...))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDBasMwDIbveQo1hzWBNOyyY9cHGWMosdw4ky3j2GTLe@@cOSujbBEIBP/3/xIaExt8WvV5xdPzKMZVFn3uD2OTbarF@Arbtq1zrZGm@NbjRBOc4aWAe1XlQMzSlA2UswRWh7Ju/gLG@RQ3/Tb8l32Qa0BrjbuCT8vCeckD9KIIrsL6cNmsTiJ8UoRMqoSRVAOOSE2AEGjAxLvY95y3OaUbqd9v7ZicIrURnbDa6YzdYwowG9duTBwIjlPyFKCTmY87XolDVjDe6JCsJk35F7/Ua1FoCWDAOLh/80f1wbhY6crUdZGPWr@cnHrsB/oG)

Comment: [28 bytes in Julia 1.0](https://tio.run/##ZZBRTsQwDET/ewpvP9hEKhUcYOEgCKGkcdoUJ47SRF16@dKyQiuovyzNm7E1YyGnnq@rvazq8WVkF4RXV@eLb8XiolBt20op14xT/ujUhBNc4K2C@4h6QCJu6gbqmROZUy2bv4ALseRdvy3/5Zi4T8p7F3qIZVloO/IAHRuEnsmeXndr4AxfmGEjTVEZTQMB0UygIOGgCh1iP7e83cl6xO54VRMGg2YnNJM56KT0U0kwu9DuTB4QzlOJmEDzTOcDbzgoMjDe6FS8RYtbF7/Ue1VZTuDABbi3@aPG5EKmIKxwUlbbW@s3)

Answer (score 3):

## J, 25 bytes

```
>./&.(a.&i.)@(<.&#{."1,:)
```

## explanation

half the bytes go to solving ensuring both inputs have the shorter inputs length (would love to see an improvement on this portion, if anyone has one):

```
(<.&#{."1,:)
```

`<.&#` is the minimum of the two lengths, and `{."1,:` takes that many characters from both rows of the 2-row table consisting of the left string stacked on top of the right one.

```
>./&.(a.&i.)
```

Use the Under verb `&.` to convert each character to its ascii index, take the maximum of the two numbers, and then convert back to characters.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LctBCoMwFATQvaf4REgUytduS1tKD9A7GPPV2JCUaMjCw6dB3Q0zb@aUhgfCExuOVYdcY/2q7sjLDdn1cqsL6icH4qvtKGAA4eRM/Srg80ZwuTx3acgqUjuRzqgD5GRPYDrZBg9RW9zROhGwJfzIZxUNOw65bcMSovZYpPQH)

Comment: 21 bytes ``[:>./&.(3&u:)<.&#$&>;``

Comment: @miles, elegant combination of train and conjunction -- i need to use that trick more to avoid parens.  also `u:` was a TIL for me.

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell, 75 bytes

```powershell
-join(1..(($a,$b=$args)|sort l*)[0].length|%{(,$a[$_-1],$b[$_-1]|sort)[1]})
#            ^input array unpack
#       ^string index generation offset by 1
#                         ^sort by length property, so output length matches shorter input
#                                           ^loop over indices
#                                       max of the two characters^
# ^output join
```

Save as .ps1 file and run

```powershell
PS C:\> .\Get-MultipliedString.ps1 'hello,' 'world!'
worlo,
```

Previously, 78 bytes:

```powershell
$i=0;-join$(while(($a=$args[0][$i])-and($b=$args[1][$i++])){($a,$b)[$b-gt$a]})
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 22 bytes

Takes two (or more!) strings as right argument.

```apl
{⎕UCS⌈⌿⎕UCS↑⍵↑¨⍨⌊/≢¨⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1NbsIwEIX3nGJgQTZQuEEXPULFAWxmEgITj@XYQgF1i1oUEF30Al1xAdZIPYovQt2qFcpm5knf@1GWx9goluJ2qwL70nITd6dtPH7Mnp5j@xrb65/evcfDJd2vczycY7ufxLfPH315uUchK40NPvv/vd6dWCeFU1VVmgJs2GyYahjCXJCgEM77jyllxENDHpIRg/KEIzBEWIMCRwsVuNO4SlUpJHpJ8@6WZjJImKAWxg5ipafBwbo0Dwn7BcGgDpYcaFnzoGNFMYoRlr9GF6qccupn3w)

`{` an anonymous function where the right argument is represented by *⍵*

`⎕UCS` the symbols from the **U**nicode **C**haracter **S**et which correspond to the

`⌈⌿` maximum value in each column of

`⎕UCS` the code points from the **U**nicode **C**haracter **S**et for the

`↑` matrified (matrix from list of strings)

`⍵` arguments

`↑¨⍨` each capped at the

`⌊/` minimum of

`≢¨` the lengths

`⍵` of the arguments

`}`

Comment: A slightly different take {⎕UCS⍺(⌊⍥⍴⍴⌈⍥⎕UCS)⍵}

Comment: @1_am_Jack That's amazing. Why don't you post that yourself? Also, I think it can be just `⎕UCS⌊⍥⍴⍴⌈⍥⎕UCS` or as I would put it `⎕UCS⌊⍥≢↑⌈⍥⎕UCS`

Comment: Thanks. tio.run doesn't appear to like that function composition operator... wasn't sure if having a way to try it online was a requirement.

Comment: @1_am_Jack I realise now that it won't work, because `⌈⍥⎕UCS` is applied first, and will LENGTH ERROR :-( However, for next time: TIO is running an old version of Dyalog APL. `⍥` is available in [Dyalog Extended](https://tio.run#apl-dyalog-extended) or you can "poly-fill" it in the Header field as `Ö←{(⍵⍵ ⍺)⍺⍺(⍵⍵ ⍵)}` (and then use `Ö` instead of `⍥`).

Comment: Good to know, thanks for your help. I only came across APL a month ago, your code golf answers have been very helpful 

Comment: @1_am_Jack Great to hear. Are you aware of https://apl.chat and https://apl.wiki? How about [APL Seeds](https://dyalog.com/apl-seeds-user-meetings/aplseeds21.htm)?

Comment: Just apl.wiki. Though I've been referring to aplcart.info, and watching code_report videos on youtube. I'll check out those others. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8 + Eclipse Collections, <s>70</s> 64 bytes

```
a->b->a.zip(b).collect(p->(char)Math.max(p.getOne(),p.getTwo()))
```

`a` and `b` are both `MutableList<Character>` from eclipse collections.

Answer (score 2):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 43 bytes

```
]w(x^
o|p
d(
do
X0l)x
`=`X(
€(=0p
rr€l<
```

#### Explanation:

First, we read the first string, and explode it, then we move a stack to the left, read the second string, and explode it:

```
€(
rr€
```

Now, we check for emptiness of either of the stacks and exit if that is the case:

```
X0l)
`=`X
  =0
   l
```

Next, we duplicate the top letter of both stacks, and convert them to code points, then move them both (and us) on the right stack:

```
]
o
d(
do
```

The `w` tests if something is less or equal. If so, we get mirrored to the right. Otherwise, we print the top letter, go on the left stack, drop the top element (the other letter) and move up (`^`), which moves us on the bottom `<`, which moves us back to the length check.

```
 w(x^
 |p
```

If however, the test was truthy, we get mirrored into the emptiness on the right, and we need to do the opposite. Eventually we reach the three commands that now drop, *then* move to the left stack and print *its* top element. The `<` is the same symbol we land on in the other case, so here too we are lead back to the length check.

```
x
(
p
<
```

This repeats until one of the length checks succeeds, i.e. if one of the input strings is exhausted.

Answer (score 2):

## k, 14 bytes

```
{|/(&/#:'x)$'x}
```

Examples:

```
k)F:{|/(&/#:'x)$'x}
k)F("hello,";"world!")
"worlo,"
```

[`q`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/card/) translation:

```
{max(min count each x)$/:x}
```

Free interpreter available [here](https://kx.com/download/)

Comment: Can you provide a Try It Online or similar? At the moment, K doesn't produce the correct output on [Kona](https://tio.run/##y9bNzs9L/P/fzaq6Rl9DTV/ZSr1CU0W9ova/m4ZSRmpOTr6OkrVSeX5RToqikuZ/AA) or [oK](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/382qukZfQ01f2Uq9QlNFvaL2v5uGUkZqTk6@jpK1Unl@UU6KopLmfwA)

Comment: I added a link to download the interpreter. Kona is an implementation of an old version of k. oK is an implementation of the k6 spec (http://kparc.com/k.txt), which doesn't have a reference implementation from kx yet.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 22 bytes

```
0({"1\:~@,"0/)<.&#$&>;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HczNTsMwEEXhfZ/iNqAYpCgNXTZQWLHiESohO578MfVEjq2IIvHqwWR79OmM69ri5YTq4Sd7upx@34qsOjw@l/ndfX6udztqesHHO0YZ3Bz84Dp8HtHm5flwgeqJWQpVq0U8271CDTV56by@Xv/pFG83phk5GrGETrjdvybuJOCbAhK0UQeyBRyRnaHhqdeRt9NXWiQsZqQmbMUwOUs2RSNst8TaVNFjGVyZcugJ2Rwn8jCycKbW9Q8)

### Explanation

```
0({"1\:~@,"0/)<.&#$&>;  Input: string x (LHS), string y (RHS)
                 #      Get length of x and y
              <.&       Minimum of those
                     ;  Link x and y as a pair of boxed strings
                  $&>   Shape each to the minimum length
         ,"0/           Reduce by joining elementwise
     \:~@               Grade down each pair
0 {"1                   Select the value at index 0 from each
```

Comment: unfortunately my idea `f=:{.@/:~"1@|:@,:` has trailing spaces and fails when one or other string is one character long

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <del>158</del> 151 bytes

Golfed:

```
String s(String a,String b){String r="";for(int i=0;i<Math.min(a.length(),b.length());i++){char c=a.charAt(i);char d=b.charAt(i);r+=c>d?c:d;}return r;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
String s(String a,String b) {
    String r = "";
    for(int i=0; i < Math.min(a.length(),b.length()); i++) {
        char c = a.charAt(i);
        char d = b.charAt(i);
        r += c > d ? c : d; //absolute ternary abuse
    }
    return r;
}
```

Takes two strings in `a` and `b`.

Comment: I think you could save a few bytes by getting rid of the outside ternary if statement  (`r+=c==d?c:`) since if they are equal you can add either `c` or `d` to the string and it won't make a difference.

Comment: 79 bytes: `a->b->r->{for(int i=0;i<a.length&i<b.length;i++)r.append(a[i]>b[i]?a[i]:b[i]);}`, which is a `Function<char[],Function<char[],Consumer<StringBuilder>>>` and outputs by modifying the StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 55 bytes

```
[A|T]*[B|U]-[C|R]:-(A>B,C=A;C=B),T*U-R.
[]*_-[].
_*L-L.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc1BboMwEIXhfU4xyaIiyEZdt0ojYJsVSVYIgYknQDp4kDFCjXJ36vYE7N/3v8EycSPHuVuWPH5dijBPXtdC5ukrKz5kEH8lIj3En@kh2YtLeJVZtMmLsJR5EW3K8CRP0XKUULVIxKIKq5kt6W0lMwGjs51pylur7BicBWR7AbPtHJIJzvto8@cGy41Vfe@HMEzPJ@EIb3BjjdAw3bdHnzTs4Acd@KGelEMtwCDqERRYbNVEq9@@/cIHuX7gza1WNaHRqD2smfRqRqp@nyzMnYk8dS3CbpwGtFDzTLvVGc1GkYbHf8RO/R3vuF3Fl18)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Can't seem to do better than 9. Takes input as a 2D array of characters, outputs an array of characters

```
ñÊÕfÎËñ Ì
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&header=Tm1x&code=8crVZs7L8SDM&input=ImhlbGxvLCIKIndvcmxkISI) (header formats the input)

```
ñÊÕfÎËñ Ì     :Implicit input of 2D array
ñ             :Sort by
 Ê            :  Length
  Õ           :Transpose, padding the shorter array with null if necessary
   f          :Filter by
    Î         :  First element (removing the arrays that contain null)
     Ë        :Map
      ñ       :  Sort
        Ì     :  Last element
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang/), <s>70</s> <s>51</s> 48 bytes

```
;=aP;=bP W&a b;O+A I>a bAaAb"\";=aGa 1La=bGb 1Lb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVlRU9tIEn62f8XgFLbGlhNZcFVbNrKLZIGilgALyeUBfIksj7HqZMknybCEsH89190zI41sk7vcLQ@WNfN1T/c3Pd09JujeBcH3V2EcRKupOMjyaZi8ng/r5kgUTipDQf64FGugNIzvKkN5uJCYqZiFsWBRxKIkvqOPejH64fzje9YrX68/XDG3fP374RXbL1@Pz9@xX8rXq4@sV4KPz64N7PnHMwP68fz94fVvVsaZhR9N9mfvb7yYPbyGZeVkMPdT1ualgIkCWwsVwyHbL@fOjz7hZAyT5NE3ht8PDtYwuAxh0E3ARBFHYAXz9uLijED4MSIn@@ibYcjViQSAvGHrvR@tBOc38ZjX6@QH7MrN2LtqHF0cW98Hnn858CaX7FPTZ5PBReeQnQ7h26F/OGncNmD6xGe9M9@bnEzgOfnOQawxkJraoEr4C@ahzkG9Dgsv/TQTFmdP9VoY5ywc1GswSkbYrD1bxQGMkHAA7/liaWfL@MYde0@O7TyDjloI6ggPTwcH3rxB9eGSPczDXGRLPxD1GnyPhAXjIG5JM2zWuM1v49vZbcqenm/GFu@/anAypRbOmFVY67HWqxZnUoUe3YHR2xiGOx05AnbWRJQJc@BZmhPMRfBPNktSFq8WE5Fmyh5mhdk0vAtzrRVWR3d6duGRfLZZz2Ed1laWdzqcdVnLacESaGnIWSryVRozHTZSjCJnsG7DvZ@G/iQS2gowIkoeRGoFsJ42hH37xrRxAb0FRMTnFlf0hFtcD72eDXvkFcNr1uFBVAELkHi6Wlq4pUxx2mXwtmmwTAuZ1CbNuG21SpsaLblpIAweFEYxUAJpBL6DZUs/y1k@F6DMT3MAqw1oa0ZxQwOOnmhjjdP1orHw2eO00bWSDDIfQzcPkxjMxoh1xmBaoBnJVsslEs51VOkRk34z/oB2g2zUoUN5GUMcQ0rDyFWWS1Y@tIpzLweOcQDTWx/TGpqpg4wyonTVQrvRVD@KksDad@weRwdxuHCCHIxXUeSnj6aj5f5cGdtz2SosowWV/Cpek6YleriESgrbPD08evvuy@87Z79eGA6baifhVr3upt6diuKT0@sXNOYiJZV@PGX/Wvn6FdXem0vsbS4hCThpFVycbuGChPerwlXMM6XKdBXjDg1UWm7nSWbpXEkHAEI7DwNGs5PV7MbdHys75EY3KT0UBmRLOFb5zAIo@L8bRdOGzjtUlmxUsq4ADkWhQBY8uX4Fd8B6e1U/0XmMxRFr5OlKNCAGi3EMSRif@ZBBcKKBkdUoSUA/0XdVmYiOz2@TJIKZSZWBF30t3fqRQ@2f98g0c7JhZoQ2xn@pjRC0eRJFlmmqzRwbKsT/YHK8YTJW4feHl@c21mIZaPB6etNzHAfCCVyBV/2WhV/F55zhY2DEqOEtMgBvNn649Lnn9XRJxwyHVR0f9OnKxx4Ajk/PjtpsBslxUCtCW62HaTjwl3YkYuoADK504yQ5g3P3EhnrglibsLRhwbFC6iWgFh8QFwMoKiFOFnkjWCzXdoBICsdlCkGawjEukz2EeTC32sDMRp8FHDH1F2Cdah22@gxXkQAPCcVODbIwb5JTSr3qFSshywdUhUsENaR5iqWLetKbMX8qwwwaKMrtcuErWLiqO4WMZ/Gm88cM/0rkJSBBq@ToTuQRtJNWk/ayiTuEJXIaxnwQziyL9hMbgmCeoi02xCnncps9Z7DVVnhwagPkekdyPdk5YjZQhAy0vUiSyp2llW9LfyS@mHlXzqCkSXGB@QIYjAaIP2@ZLEVsGQvbjbRBrQJY5S1kpYR49Fxn/xcaV82FJTuSGZg@RaeghYOQtbG/Azj0DvSGa8DSOrwsGGQdj1ohPLGA5Ipu0ENrEdWooe0x1@xZShpLT34HT8Qf0Mbhad/wc6ey63Rr2MFMtgE82wgPWCWq8mLAf231VZ@4JZCLzKcqUOOc2mILaxDXRWg43OdlY7mRDrXoNTWH1m6GgtXDsCkMdELrY64LmZQ3SqiewPIi/FipfamEqZpl7oDKLYqFi5IFPBjy4oOkyf2sUMeaTbpqdbsIHcs295ba7Zo2a/d1OwN7LHjjTB@11DB/lWd694uYkL2eNKhTGER5EvIlpmQMLWN7ZDddq@62vLciGvp@pmPJlXuO/S8dBrkBhMJhPOWe9tLl20M18HP9UF1nr1PSxPV31MWhG7XpmascofzqbkSnEe3YqlftlULtcne2sLBenrfw0N7gQe7rNhYWW1xrE8YzlZAA1CCLMqTXuoVLHoIG3S7pU0RRyVzfaMloXjn9b35IzJvtxOz@UGh3u9A/iM2KQ/LqQGOu6eVA0S5Z91i3V7BMWKC@B@es24Mz1jPB7k@iDyA9VrCeh1Bat69HHE05Ee0OHcW1y6ldaXvEf339QNAkuQJ3BEqwWGLgO14Z5iIVrYzFCfTQYZSHMXvwH4E3Nk3gTpqLO5GCzDKJRZyHPt4i4CQn7EGwuX8vAKgUITxnCz9eQfg8vsZR9G6CjAMVxES2inL80YAWLxKehnRNjF5yjTJTroCsqUd9LyOdlw0pYAcVlEP3cz/C2vgIXsfTSEzZl9LsL4WWJ/wmGzNjkdKZISrrdvU7J3hNQduG6c9FHjygYF0rfJj0KnnRq2bFETMP/4F5DFC0r36RazIJGLFKo0iDNjOyIepwpKQuua6sA4jd8aDaGF3QEA4lhlYyTfpsIRbBEsMsZsMvo//XleFf4MpQu7KzxRdP@aJcGb3Mvlx1i8k4PWIVgFsgXF1Ad7bZWb4U7unMYyoozGuW6Q992VYbRqakSiWF/Lf/Rl7lIENNIT9o9U10pc1dx3pl1q1O//RFRve25U0GcbXKbaZIhYRBjWOvIm2kSZRARKdTiEmTP4F78lcvs9GseMfM3kWJnVa7doQa8iO3v2fQciKvDJ7RYXXMArR5R4rVxcMuzsJepaG9lkSvKR2slzx3W8nb40Uf4BbS@zT4HxoiNAyfuBVB0fwX7ZDZG7ngIa7a6WGTRA2CjH85SQ9CdNRJgNWnYuZDkgTPdIcZxjAZTulHJD/IoUy1doMW9pw4wtkLt1hUVtRA6AbVDwkLP4yxWWV@ehfYpLTdhu/3HH@uovsl/oPHcsia6jXu@fsyTe5Sf7GA/h46269fI5HB0Q@SqWB3STTbGdXjJGePImcAm@Ivc1ObxUJMM@bDBs/BtX8D)

Ungolfed & explained:

```
; = a PROMPT                                  # a = input()
; = b PROMPT                                  # b = input()
: WHILE & a b                                 # while a != "" and b != "":
    ; OUTPUT + ASCII IF > a b ASCII           #
               a ASCII b "\"                  #    print(a[0] if a > b else a[1]) # (without newline)
    ; = a GET a 1 LENGTH a                    #    a = a[1:]
    : = b GET b 1 LENGTH b                    #    b = b[1:]
```

-19 bytes thanks to Adam.

-3 bytes thanks to Bubbler.

Comment: 51 bytes: `;=aP;=bP W&a b;O+I>AaAbA AaA Ab"\";=aGa 1La=bGb 1Lb`. However, I think this program relies on undefined behavior for `GET`, since `(LENGTH a)+1` is outside the bounds of the string.

Comment: @Adam Thanks. Undefined behavior is accepted as long as it works.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: You can factor out the `A` of `A Aa` and `A Ab` out of `I`, and simplify `>AaAb` to `>a b` (because `a>b` guarantees `a[0]>=b[0]` and `not(a>b)` guarantees `a[0]<=b[0]`).

Comment: @Bubbler It doesn't actually save bytes to factor out `A A` because then it requires more spaces. It does save 1 though by using `>a b`

Comment: No, only one A. So `I>a bA AaA Ab` -> `A I>a bAaAb`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>131</s> 121 bytes

```go
func f(a,b string)(o string){
if""==a||b==""{o=""}else{A,B:=a[:1],b[:1]
if A>B{o+=A}else{o+=B}
o+=f(a[1:],b[1:])}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZBBasMwEEXp1vQQEy2KTd3Q7ErALckJug8FS9bIcSJrjCwREscn6SYUeogepT1N5aSF1ps_A__N10evbyWdPhpebHmJUPPKRFXdkHVTpmrH3r1Tdw-fe-VNASrmqYDW2cqUSUy_WxdVirEs48ejyDLGOgrSo26xW6TLecZX89lLKgYNJCwelx3dZosLEbZlHwUN4avZfOCCJn1k0Xlr-kuBr6vrc4OhX5xAFz2Hl502sYrZGrWmlEEKbEdWywlLkj9-3lgqLa_rUBUafzhobOEGCpIIJWk1ecrT3JCDPToIoPTcoUzBIMoWOFhcc6_z_5nbEBbOSGywcCNPaDQSZbAFaTkyNRf33sKuMtMAuDUCa32DFgTtNBvBkgzXEjZn1PpaocIB-fmU0-kyvwE)

- -10 by @The Thonnu

Comment: [121 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZBBasMwEEXp1vQQEy2KTd3Q7ErALckJug8FS9bIcSJrjCwREscn6SYUeogepT1N5aSF1ps_A__N10evbyWdPhpebHmJUPPKRFXdkHVTpmrH3r1Tdw-fe-VNASrmqYDW2cqUSUy_WxdVirEs48ejyDLGOgrSo26xW6TLecZX89lLKgYNJCwelx3dZosLEbZlHwUN4avZfOCCJn1k0Xlr-kuBr6vrc4OhX5xAFz2Hl502sYrZGrWmlEEKbEdWywlLkj9-3lgqLa_rUBUafzhobOEGCpIIJWk1ecrT3JCDPToIoPTcoUzBIMoWOFhcc6_z_5nbEBbOSGywcCNPaDQSZbAFaTkyNRf33sKuMtMAuDUCa32DFgTtNBvBkgzXEjZn1PpaocIB-fmU0-kyvwE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 34 bytes

```rust
|a,b|a.zip(b).map(|(i,j)|i.max(j))
```

which takes in two iterators over `char`s and returns another. This only works by shunting the following obscene type into the header code:

```rust
for<'a> fn(std::str::Chars<'a>, std::str::Chars<'a>) -> std::iter::Map<std::iter::Zip<std::str::Chars<'a>, std::str::Chars<'a>>, fn((char, char))->char>
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVK7stMwEB1K5ys2LkCacTyXWzEm1xTUVHTkZhg5khwFWTJ6TCCJv4QmBbT8At9x-RpWdjxDQUFhrc7Zs2dHu_723UUfrk8_pYGOKUMonBeZFgFkBdK69QtWgzTEB15VPriqertnzie6gH-QFFb1xKsgMPGO9eu_4Ad1g_9hhSw2JjvEBaST0lWdYg0PP2KQq1dP-YUVzYWVJ9WThpYd68mFqOJALwrBF3KgdFL-fvYre73I8EGwUeZlAcrcF2Bj2OINNossS1-W9862jnWdMi308XTSwsNz2FkuoLVaLt_kxagzNsBXHBKKeWRB8AKMENwDAyf2LOq8gJthaFHYKdfyOBmOQjR0aIhClG2T6Sb_hF2xLrfNQezCeEvMLdtoYbjgiW6snqOZ05o1d9HBUZkypcJewGPuYy8cNPaoH_Mbexd9PCpXznXcGqY5HKYqFzsppFjOQAuJme0i26bfIuudMmFJcknOOMWhAAz3A4UHyCmON2PeCxc-is9LIgkqyrQuT-g47xnQcme1xhdW1fp9QMe2Tgpcxugx9tAGu5yRGkbjYTFMe7xep_gH)

If iterators over chars do not count as reasonable input/output I can instead manage

## 60 bytes

```rust
|a,b|a.chars().zip(b.chars()).map(|(i,j)|i.max(j)).collect()
```

which has the much more reasonable type of

```rust
fn(&str, &str) -> String
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NVFLbtswEEWX1CnGXAQkwAhpVkXzO0SXjlFQJinToUiFH7i1rZNk40V7qPQ0HUnWQhrO-5GY-fgTS8qXz9p46KT1jMOpIk5nMN_BeHaTchQw_jncPsOPHK1v4elvyeb22-fjWYrmLOvtTsbEeH20PWuWjted7NmZWbHnZ4vNL7ZHcBuc09vM-Jzx78sHeaiICRHW1n8VYP29gFDyBk-wrggZP0L7GNoou268vi_Ho9MJbmAblIY2OLN6oWLS-ZDhNz4fxarIrJUAr7VKICHqnSyOCrgG5haFnY2tKnPgJMTAiIEoRNlmDF3TN7wVfTQ0e3z6dBqRK9s47ZVWI9wEt1S_0E42dyXCwfp6pPJOwytNpdcRmnBwr_SK3pVUDjbWi08FL52C_eyKpTPa6NXSOG2Q2VRkMy6M9LiXvGLUsBNOcRCA5X7g8ASU43iJTEnH_FO_r5hhy5z5NOiJn_zOY8IJoWEyDdUw7-hymet_)

Answer (score 2):

## [tinylisp 2](https://github.com/dloscutoff/tinylisp2), 28 bytes

```lisp
(\(S T)(,(zip-with max S T)"
```

Try it at [Replit](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/tinylisp2)! Example session:

```
tl2> (\(S T)(,(zip-with max S T)"
(() (S T) (, (zip-with max S T) ""))
tl2> (d F _
F
tl2> (F "hello," "world!")
"worlo,"
```

#### Explanation

The library functions `zip-with` and `max` do almost the entire task.* The only catch is that `zip-with` returns a list of codepoints, and we want a string. The easiest way to convert is to concatenate an empty string using `,` (short for `concat`).

---

* When I first answered this challenge, I had not yet implemented `zip-with` and `max` in the standard library. Here's my original **46-byte** solution without those functions:

```lisp
(\(S T)(,(m(p a(\(C D)(?(< C D)D C)))(z S T))"
```

Explanation:

```lisp
(\(S T)(,(m(p a(\(C D)(?(< C D)D C)))(z S T))""))
(\                                              ) ; Lambda function
  (S T)                                           ; taking two strings S and T:
                                     (z S T)      ; Zip (-> list of pairs of codepoints)
         (m                                 )     ; Map to each pair:
           (p a                     )             ; Apply to its two items:
               (\                  )              ; Lambda function
                 (C D)                            ; taking two integers C and D:
                      (?(< C D)D C)               ; If C < D, then D, else C (i.e. max)
                                                  ; Now we have a list of codepoints...
       (,                                    "")  ; Concat "", converting to string
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 102 bytes

```
T=ToCharacterCode;L=Length;(a=T@#;b=T@#2;FromCharacterCode@Table[Max[a[[i]],b[[i]]],{i,L@a~Min~L@b}])&
```

**input**

> ["blended
> ", "bold"]

Comment: `L@a~Min~L@b` saves one byte

Answer (score 1):

## [Micro](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Micro), 119 bytes

```
{R b i m+:R}:X{R a i m+:R}:Y
""\\:a:b:R
{b:M}:N
a:M
b a<if(N,)
0:i{i1+:i
a i m C b i m C~:> if(X,Y)
i M=if(,Z)}:Z
Z
R:\
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <s>71</s>, 67 bytes

*saved a few bytes by using `string.Join()` instead of `new string()`*

added 18 bytes to both versions for needing `using System.Linq;`

**67 bytes**

```
(a,b)=>string.Join("",(a.Zip(b,(x,y)=>x>y?x:y)));
```

**71 bytes:**

```
(a,b)=>new string(a.Zip(b,(x,y)=>x>y?x:y).ToArray());
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ePb5Ee)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 17 bytes

```
Ｆ⌊⟦ＬθＬη⟧⌈⟦§θι§ηι⟧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzczLzO3NFcj2ic1L70kQ6NQU0cByszQjNXUVAgoyswr0fBNrIAocyzxzEtJrdAo1FHIBCqFcTNAXKBy6///szPz0rnyk7JSk0v@65b91y3OAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: `Slice` got added a few days later, which would have allowed the following code for 15 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMqtEBHwTexQCM4JzM5VaNQR8FAR8EnNS@9JEMjQ1NHwVATJF2RmVuaqxGdqaPgWOKZl5JaoZGho5CtGaupqWn9/392Zl46V35SVmpyyX/dsv@6xTkA)

```
↑Ｅ✂θ⁰Ｌη¹⌈⟦ι§ηκ⟧
```

Comment: 9 bytes instead of 15, not sure if I had this back in June so maybe it's valid lol :P https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBI7UsMacssUhDqUpJRyG6UEchI1ZTUyGgKDOvRMM3sSIztzRXI1NT0/r//@zMvHSu/KSs1OSS/7pl/3WLcwA

Answer (score 1):

## Modern Pascal

***version 1 of algorithm (func:139bytes)***

```
   for var l:=1 to min(length(paramstr(1)),length(paramstr(2))) do
      result+=iif(paramstr(1)[l]>paramstr(b)[l],paramstr(1)[l],paramstr(2)[l]);
```

**Explanation**
The for loop is designed to crawl to the length of the shortest string.
The output is compared appending to result the highest ASCII value of
each letter crawled. Since we are using shortest length, we can access
the strings elements directly - see v2 below, uses Copy() to be safer.

***version 2 of algorithm (func:166bytes)***

```
   for var l:=1 to max(length(paramstr(1)),length(paramstr(2))) do
      result+=iif(copy(paramstr(1),l,1)>copy(paramstr(2),l,1),copy(paramstr(1),l,1),copy(paramstr(2),l,1));
```

// Author of Modern Pascal

Comment: Welcome to our site! This contest is a [tag:code-golf] contest.  You should aim to minimize the number of bytes in the source code.  I don't know pascal at all so this may be well golfed already but I suspect there is some whitespace that can be removed.  Once you are satisfied with your golfs you can add the byte count of your program to your header.  If you have any questions you can ping me with `@wheatwizard`.

Comment: As Wheat Wizard said, I'm sure this can be golfed to reduce your score but I think that there is at least one typo in your first code, maybe two. Should `iif(a[l]>b[l]),a[l]` be `if(a[l]>b[l],a[l]`? (there is definitely an extra `)` but I don't know about `iif` and `if`)

Comment: shortened. Good find on the extra paren. fixed. In MP, I added iff() to mimic ?(eval,true,false).

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 9 bytes

```
DQSS_MaZb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fJTA4ON43MSrp////Gak5Ofk6/8vzi3JSFAE)

Pip doesn't have a string max operator, so I used `SS` (Sort String) instead:

```
      aZb  Zip the two cmdline args together, truncating to shorter length
     M     To that list of 2-element lists of characters, map a function:
  SS_       Sort each pair of characters stringwise
DQ          and dequeue the second (larger) one
           Autoprint the resulting list of characters
```

Answer (score 1):

## [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 186 bytes

```
N
Count i while _/128^i/32 {
_+128^(i+1)*N
}
_*128+N
Count i while _%128/32*(_/4096) {
Count j while _/128%128/(_%128+1) {
_/128^2*128^2+_/128%128+_%128*128
}
Write _%128
_/128^2*128+N
}
```

Input strings should be given on stdin, newline-separated. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/9@Pyzm/NK9EIVOhPCMzJ1UhXt/QyCIuU9/YSKGaK14bxNHI1DbU1PLjquWK1wLytTG0qAJFgRq0NOL1TQwszTSBOiEqspANBavSACsGmgcyHWyVkRaY1Iar0QYrAYkCbQwvyiyB2oCsHuiG2v//M1JzcvJ1uMrzi3JSFAE)

#### Explanation

We conceptually partition the accumulator into 7-bit registers, each of which can hold an input character. The first `Count i` loops until the input's ASCII code is smaller than 32, storing the first line of input into the accumulator, with the first character in the least-significant position:

```
, o l l e h
5 4 3 2 1 0
Accumulator value = asc(h) + 128*asc(e) + 128^2*asc(l) + ... = 1541853098728
```

Next, we shift everything left by one register, read the first character of the second line, and store it into register 0:

```
, o l l e h w
6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

We `Count i` again while register 0 (`_%128`) and register 1 (`_/128%128`, though the formula can be golfed a bit in this context) are both >= 32. Inside the loop, we use a nested `Count j` loop to check if register 1 is strictly greater than register 0. (Comparisons are done via integer division: if `a/(b+1)` is `0`, then `a<=b`; if `a/(b+1)` is nonzero, then `a>b`.) If it is greater, we swap the registers' contents. This loop executes at most once, because after swapping, the condition is guaranteed not to be true anymore.

After the (potential) swap, the larger of the two characters is in register 0, which we output. We then shift two registers to the right (`_/128^2`), shift one register back to the left (`*128`), and store the next input character in register 0 (`+N`):

```
, o l l e o
5 4 3 2 1 0
```

The `Count i` loop exits once one or both strings reach the newline at their end.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-lF`, <s>88</s> 67 bytes

```perl
@b=<>=~/./g;$#F=$#b=@F>@b?$#b:$#F;say map{($q=shift@b)gt$_?$q:$_}@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcgxDoMgFADQvacg@od2EOngokWZ2HoGw0@oklBBwJimaY9e6vbyvA62yVkgv/X8W9N66qCUHErkQvYCh0PtMV1UL/JU/n2GlcfZPJLAy5RgHGBtYfwImbNVyLZAdrPQU5o1KeLmdSDodlv8nE/GLTFX94ayK8uVlX8)

Answer (score 1):

## Axiom, <s>67</s> 20 bytes

```
f(a,b)==map(max,a,b)
```

And with this we now surpass JavaScript, Lisp until perhaps J and APL too.

The previous solution:

```
f(a,b)==concat[max(a.x,b.y)::String for x in 1..#a for y in 1..#b]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 59 bytes

```
(lambda(x y)(map'string(lambda(a b)(if(char> a b)a b))x y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYpBDoAgDAS/UnuxTXyDfymgQlKEgIn6eoSDhzns7FgNNTfKJZwWqJFKNE7ogZcpSp7r1Z/j1wKGKexkvZQVxhrwqLmh31TTgoB3Kuom5C4/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Whispers](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 49 bytes

```
> Input
> Input
>> L»R
>> Each 3 1 2
>> Output 4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSr@/99OwTOvoLSEC07bKfgc2h0Eol0TkzMUjBUMFYxAPP/SEqC8gsn//0k5qXkpqSlcSfk5KQA)

### How it works

Each line consists of `(line no.) (> or >>) (command)` (the line numbers are implicitly added in the actual program)

```
1 > Input        - Retrieve the first input

2 > Input        - Retrieve the second input

3 >>  »          - Take the maximum of...
     L           -   the left argument and...
       R         -   the right argument

4 >> Each        - For each value in...
            1    -   the first line zipped with...
              2  -   the second input,
          3      -   call the third line

5 >>        4    - Run the fourth line, then...
     Output      - Output the result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift](https://swift.org), 66 bytes

```
func f(a:String,b:String){print(String(zip(a,b).map{max($0,$1)}))}
```

Straight forward solution

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 13 bytes

```
ÊmVl)îUcÈwVcY
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=ym1WbCnuVWNAWHdWY1k=&input=IkhlbGxvLCIgIldvcmxkIg==)

#### Unpacked & How it works

```
Ul mVl)îUcXYZ{XwVcY

Ul      Length of 1st input (U)
mVl)    Minimum of above and length of 2nd input (V)
î       Take this length out of the following string...
UcXYZ{    Map on charcodes of U and convert back to string...
Xw          Maximum of this and...
VcY         V's charcode at the same index.
```

Japt doesn't have min/max on strings, but does have one on numbers. Turns out that it helped reduce bytes on both "Compute minimum length of two strings" and "Map on two strings to take higher chars".

Answer (score 1):

## Cjam, 3 bytes

This is so easy...

```
.e>
```

Pretty much the same as the Haskell answer, `.` takes an operator and performs "`zipWith`", and `e>` means take the max of the two inputs.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#cjam)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 23 bytes

```
~zip{.,({$1=}{;}if}%''+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1BTsQwDADvvMIbKEViVS1nhHjIikPaONmUNImcWBWtyteLt9wSz3jsUrBlIJ/rHpt1/118Xrvzy/r09rGt75u3W9O2r3vmWrZmv6pMyZGeJh8dZF6WgAWeYUgGwUnq9KlAxVThByuIaFhXNGeIiKaABsKb5qC@4BEyVSfW5MkZ/i8dlpRIShwerupbzkgw9SMO9dhKMhHQB4wGjbA@BXMQeUQhQfcXJph97BS09YagCmck4XNQ7d2U4YULz546WTAp6mBgFF1V4smixdNRvP8C2rH7Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 96 bytes

```r
for(i in 1:min(lengths(m<-sapply(scan(,""),utf8ToInt))))cat(intToUtf8(max(m[[1]][i],m[[2]][i])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBCsMgEAC/Il7cgC1NT6X0A72nJ/FggmkWdBXdkPb1VjqnYZjS2poKoEAS4z0iQfD05q1CfJyqyzl8oS6OQEs56J3X25SexENncQxIPKVXrxDdB6Ixo7UGre52/Vv/mgpuvuxFHEhnJRRvXsi6Z1/EnI4gVfsB)

Using ASCII code.

Answer (score 1):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 46 bytes

```erlang
t([I|M],[E|S])->[max(I,E)]++t(M,S);t(_,_)->[].
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcq7DoIwFADQ3a@4djBtKHyAJjoxMDAxNg1p4IJN@iDlEpXw71XnczA5E@YS1yHZhfIpE1fN0Wqp6qPTorwrb968kbXQRUG8lZ24Ee9l/yddZW9s4OofbbxOr2QJOXG2pDgn470NMyzbvjtc4QJDHBHm6Kbzg0kWIsEHCX5x3AzhKCEgjisYSPg0m2NCVPkL)

### Explanation

```erlang
t([I|M],[E|S])->               % Extract the head of both operands
[max(I,E)]                     % Take the max of the heads
++t(M,S);                      % Recurse with the remaining strings
t(_,_)                         % If head-extraction fails for either of these operands:
->[].                          % Return the empty string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org),  <s>23</s>  17 bytes

```
{zip(it,::maxOf)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1BDoIwEEXX9hQjqzapHqARXLAlceEJhlBk4tCSUtRIOHuFsHX1k/@S954@Mrn0Qoaxn9jAPQZyj7PcV8GpgIrGeCk7DAXkaf7SIClqY3r83Fq1pHZy0CM5qWAWh82EkEOw2FTk7PpeDWTZTuq/ZFhTUW59ibpWSiyps8xei7cP3Bx/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 9 bytes

```
lnp^q>]Z[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f8/J68grtAuNir6//@M1JycfB2u8vyinBRFAA)

Returns a list of characters add 2 bytes for concat (`\[`)

```
ln  # Split on newlines
p^  # Push to arr
q>] # Boxed maximum
Z[  # ZipWith
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
zY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcqxEYAgDAXQVb6NlTs4h2XORPAEwgEpZPnoq1@0/rjPw91r09Ao57sEVJszSceKU1kQNF3L7kUHXhn4GxsN4Q1FhDsITSJZ@gA)

zip using maximum.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
ZvG
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=ZvG&inputs=hello%2C%0Aworld!&header=&footer=)

That is: the maximum function (`G`) `v`ectorised over the inputs `Z`ipped together (`abc` and `def` turn into `[["a", "d"], ["b", "e"], ["c", "f"]]`. Takes a single string (alternatively, a list of characters) and outputs a list of characters.

Comment: Funnily enough, this is a one-to-one correspondence to 05AB1E: `Z` → `ø`, `v` → `€`, and `G` → `à`. (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
ø€à
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8I5HTWsOL/j/P1q9oCg/vSgxNzczL12hoLSqKie1WEFNITk/JVUhPT8nTdFeXUdBPS@/RKEytUQBqDKlNLEkNUVHIS81NaVYIVGhKDUjsTRHPRYA)

```
ø€à  # full program
ø    # list of...
  à  # maximums of...
 €   # each element of...
ø    # code points of...
     # implicit input...
ø    # with each element paired with the corresponding element in second sub-list
     # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>16</s> 4 bytes

```
vmax
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQma@QnVqUl5qjkJtYkqFXlgqSLFaw5lLKSM3JyddRUlAqzy/KSVFU@l@Wm1jxv6AoM6/kPwA)

Element-wise maximum. It's a builtin.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
eCSMC
```

[Test suite](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=eCSMC&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22hello%2C%22%2C+%22world%21%22%0A%22programming+puzzles+%26+code+golf%21%3F%22%2C+%22not+yet+graduated%2C+needs+a+rehaul%22%0A%22king%22%2C+%22object%22%0A%22blended%22%2C+%22bold%22%0A%22lab0ur+win.%22%2C+%27the+%22super+bowl%22%27%0A%22donald+j.%22%2C+%22trumfefe%21%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `J` `B`, \$ 5 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.12 bytes

```
ZZeMC
```

(No ATO link since it's not on a new enough version)

##### Explanation

```python
ZZeMC  # Implicit input. The B flag converts the strings to codepoints.
ZZe    # Zip together and loop through:
   M   #   Get the maximum
    C  #   And get chr of that
       # Implicit output, with the J flag joining everything together
```

#### [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `J`, \$ 9 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 7.41 bytes

```
ZZeO.AJMC
```

(No ATO link since it's not on a new enough version)

##### Explanation

Unfortunately the `max` command (`M`) doesn't work with strings, otherwise this would have been a lot simpler.

```python
ZZeO.AJMC  # Implicit input
ZZe        # Zip together and loop through:
   O.AJ    #   Get the ordinals of both characters
       M   #   Get the maximum
        C  #   And get chr of that
           # Implicit output, with the J flag joining everything together
```

##### Screenshots

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 26 bytes

```python
lambda*a:list(map(max,*a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BbsIwEETv/YrFh5Igq0LiVqniR7is2XUSuvZajq0APx/MpWoOc3pvRpr0KKPG0@p/LqtgcIQH/JZpLl3A1HK3B@z7NeUpls53ZmQRtcaaRbPQzvT9xx9LWYeMIUxxgFSfT@EZPuGqxDCo@N251aIWeHCBJlLFwmQhMtMMCJlHrLJZ/G1TraTuxteyIU44ElODToU2SNAda4Zlil/G7svIYOaaOIPTRcz@v0oaUQhuTQRTcg2ePb9PrS8)

Similar to another Python 3 answer, only that I use `list` instead of `''.join`, which shaves 3 bytes off.

Comment: `[*map(...)]` saves some over `list`

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 51 bytes

```c
f(char*s,char*t){(*s=*s>*t|!*s?*s:*t)&&f(s+1,t+1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/BasMwEETv@Yq1D0ZW5IOvNWk@pPSgSCvZIEtGu6I0br7dUQs9lM5lYJk3y5jBG3McTphZZ0nqx7jfhaSLpFfJX42kq6SXeuw6J@g8Kj6P/fQ4lsiw6iWK/rSfoGr/hkG/vcMF2hlDSKqdwAmt2o@Ug23aftoKk9AV/09sOfms13WJHrZyvwck6MAki@BTcM31tywmhk9kqGlbNKNVEBEtgYaMsy7hz5/HIWkYS50yjOBKhFthCCl6zE8)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 51 bytes

```c
f(char*s,char*t){(*s=0u-*s<-*t?*s:*t)&&f(s+1,t+1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY3LCoMwFET3fsVtFhJjhLqtFT@kdHFJ4gNiInlQqvjt1ha66Eo6m4FhzowoOiG2raWiR8c8/1jIFsp8fY4F89eChYb5yx6maUt9XvKQl1m1boMJMOJgaJYsCexa3jDg7Q41kF5pbTmpoKXIycM6LU8kq6YYPMUdPyYO2v9MT852DsdxMB1McZ618pCCsFJBZ3V7ar5jxgZ4qgB7W0YMSnIwSkkPCE71GPXPz7q9AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 22 bytes

```arturo
$=>[couple&&|map=>max]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?WidqaF)

Takes and outputs a list of characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Z€G
```

Output as a list of characters. Add the `J` flag if you want a string.

##### Explanation

```python
Z€G  # Implicit input
Z    # Zip the two inputs together
 €   # For each pair:
  G  #  Get the maximum of the pair
     # Implicit output
```

##### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does this work for inputs of different lengths?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing yes it does: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RBi7.png