# Element-wise string multiplication

Tags: code-golf, string, printable-ascii

Inspired by [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125470/multiply-two-strings) challenge (thanks @cairdcoinheringaahing for the title!), your task is to take two printable ASCII strings and multiply them element-wise with the following rules.

#### How does it work?

Given two strings (for example `split` and `isbn`) you will first, truncate the longer one such that they have equal length and then determine their [ASCII codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters):

```
split -> spli -> [115, 112, 108, 105]
isbn  -> isbn -> [105, 115,  98, 110]
```

The next step will be to map them to the range `[0..94]` by subtracting `32` of each code:

```
[115, 112, 108, 105] -> [83, 80, 76, 73]
[105, 115,  98, 110] -> [73, 83, 66, 78]
```

Now you will multiply them element-wise modulo `95` (to stay in the printable range):

```
[83, 80, 76, 73] ⊗ [73, 83, 66, 78] -> [74, 85, 76, 89]
```

Add `32` to get back to the range `[32..126]`:

```
[74, 85, 76, 89] -> [106, 117, 108, 121]
```

And the final step is to map them back to ASCII characters:

```
[106, 117, 108, 121] -> "july"
```

#### Rules

- You will write a program/function that implements the described steps on two strings and either prints or returns the resulting string
- The input format is flexible: you can take two strings, a tuple of strings, list of strings etc.
- The input may consist of one or two empty strings
- The input will be characters in the printable range (`[32..126]`)
- The output is either printed to the console or you return a string
- The output is allowed to have trailing whitespaces

#### Test cases

```
"isbn", "split"                  -> "july"
"", ""                           -> ""
"", "I don't matter"             -> ""
"             ", "Me neither :(" -> "             "
"but I do!", "!!!!!!!!!"         -> "but I do!"
'quotes', '""""""'               -> 'ck_iKg'
"wood", "hungry"                 -> "yarn"
"tray", "gzip"                   -> "jazz"
"industry", "bond"               -> "drop"
"public", "toll"                 -> "fall"
"roll", "dublin"                 -> "ball"
"GX!", "GX!"                     -> "!!!"
"4 lll 4", "4 lll 4"             -> "4 lll 4"
"M>>M", "M>>M"                   -> ">MM>"
```

**Note**: The quotes are just for readability, in the 6th test case I used `'` instead of `"`.

Comment: Are you allowed to have trailing spaces in your output?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Yes. Sorry, I added that after posting it.

Comment: Can we take an array of arrays of strings? `abc, def -> [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]`

Comment: @totallyhuman I wouldn't say so. Though, if in your language strings are arrays of chars and chars have the same type as strings,  then it would be valid I guess.

Comment: Are we allowed to take input as a list of strings?

Comment: @Zacharý If you mean `["tray", "gzip"]`, yes. That's mentioned in the challenge.

Answer (score 9):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
c32-p95\32+c
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P9nYSLfA0jTG2Eg7@f//avXigpzMEnUdBfXM4qQ89VoA)

#### Explanation

```
c      % Implicitly input cell array of 2 strings. Convert to 2-row char matrix.
       % This pads the shorter string with spaces
32-    % Subtract 32, element-wise. Each char is interpreted as its ASCII code.
       % Note that padding spaces will give 0.
p      % Product of each column. Since (padding) spaces have been mapped to 0, the
       % product effectively eliminates those colums. So the effect is the same as
       % if string length had been limited by the shorter one
95\    % Modulo 95, element-wise
32+    % Add 32, element-wise
c      % Convert to char. Implicitly display
```

Comment: Clever way of managing the string length difference.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>15</s> 12 bytes

```
z⁶O_32P€‘ịØṖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf9qZWxsef//euKBtk9fMzJQ4oKs4oCY4buLw5jhuZb///9bJ3NwbGl0JywgJ2lzYm4nXQ)

-3 thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan).

Comment: Sneaky abuse of trailing whitespace. ;)

Comment: @Dennis Well it's in the rules, why not abuse it?

Comment: I believe you can save 3 bytes by using the niladic atom for printable characters, `ØṖ`, with `z⁶O_32P€‘ịØṖ` - you'd best double check that the arithmetic works though.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Of course.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>80</s> <s>74</s> 71 bytes

```python
lambda*t:''.join(map(lambda x,y:chr((ord(x)-32)*(ord(y)-32)%95+32),*t))
```

*Thanks to @shooqie for golfing off 3 bytes!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYkxDoAgEMC@wmLuQHTQOGjiT1xQYsQoELhBXo9EpzatT3Q42@edzWzJl7pXrQRNAO3pjMVbefwje2SatiMguqDx4U3fcfF5@rwah7pACuI8@2As4Y5g4mpBQvSXISjjBQ)

Comment: 71 if you take `(s, t)` as a tuple: `lambda t:''.join(map(lambda x,y:chr((ord(x)-32)*(ord(y)-32)%95+32),*t))`

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>75</s> 70 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to Dennis' suggestion of shooqie's suggestion. -2 bytes thanks to Zacharý's suggestion.*

```python
lambda*l:''.join(chr((ord(i)-32)*(ord(j)-32)%95+32)for i,j in zip(*l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcYxDsIwDADAr3hBtkNhKGIAiZ@wtERRHQU7csNQPh9Qp7u6tcV07Onx7GV6z3EK5Y54ziZKr8WJzCMJny4jh/15/@F2Pf5J5iBDBlH4SqVQmHt10QaJUDR@1uYbDoCzaUTuPw)

Comment: Same trick that was suggested on my answer: `lambda*t:''.join(chr(((ord(i)-32)*(ord(j)-32))%95+32)for i,j in zip(*t))`

Comment: And same one that I suggested a lot: `((ord(i)-32)*(ord(j)-32))%95+32` => `(ord(i)-32)*(ord(j)-32)%95+32` ...

Comment: o_o beating Dennis. +1

Comment: Eh, not really, I just changed to a list comprehension instead of using `map`. I was just slightly late.

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>60</s> 57 bytes

```hs
zipWith(\a b->toEnum$f a*f b`mod`95+32)
f=(-32+).fromEnum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddFPa8IwFADwez7F8ylUp91B3WEDexljjFEQdtgOwkztH6Np0qUJQ8XP3iV1bhTruyQkvzxe3lvTcptwXh38LnAqMkOzBB7nc@j6R5LNFtWeFe9Mr/sLCpEfaPkkTN5Lgd6kEC1zGS/v74aT8YCks74/GQ8Ht6mSuUNVTpmAGRRGv2kFPcgAv6WMEXBtRKZ2SA4@QVZGAkeAZcGZRrgIPwDcGG41OtYiGvSXvUAshachp1onCttY48y9CRMQif1qouChjzVrGoKR0eBSd5zvnAMbqf8N8b6M1EnpjcDDOrzLir3V9pO9Zh45NWf0153W7@2oErYOrejO0cxOB690YkP3e0uZiE2pVc0jKWJsobGShaWFiThbOagl5@0FpNTeEFQOWBi7J6KdRif6/FF3yy1Xp@aaSHAKnHOYOn3eXsjzBcEwCMJ6bG69kjcIwwCJf6x@AA)

First line is an anonymous function taking two arguments.

This a straight forward implementation of the algorithm: `zipWith` takes both strings and applies a given function to the pairs of characters. It handles the truncation and also works for empty strings. `fromEnum` and `toEnum` are alternatives to `ord` and `chr` to switch between characters and their ASCII values which do not need a lengthy import.

**Edit:** -3 bytes thanks to Bruce Forte.

Comment: You can save `3` bytes by pulling out `-32` and saving those parenthesis, see [here](https://tio.run/##Fcq7DoIwAAXQna@4KQwgqQPEwaEuxp3EwYWBEugj9kFqG6PGb6/xzEfxx301Jn9oCcOdTFyuOA8DSvotJBvzW283HVU9csz0FP3FJVsJ8J3APFm/TMdD23dNIVhN@65t9iJ4@0/Zcu3AsKV4jQEVJMjT@4WAqORkeJH8Aw "Haskell – Try It Online").

Answer (score 5):

### C++, <s>331</s> <s>291</s> <s>282</s> <s>270</s> 268 bytes, Version 2 = <s>178</s> <s>176</s> <s>150</s> 148 bytes

Original Version :

```cpp
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#define L length()
#define S std::string
S m(S a,S b){S c;int m=a.L<b.L?a.L:b.L;auto l=[m](S&s){s=s.substr(0,m);std::for_each(s.begin(),s.end(),[](char&c){c-=32;});};l(a);l(b);for(int i=0;i<m;++i){c+=a[i]*b[i]%95+32;}return c;}
```

-40 bytes thanks to Bruce Forte
-39 bytes thanks to Zacharý

Version 2, inspired by other people's answers

```cpp
#include<string>
#define L length()
using S=std::string;S m(S a,S b){S c;for(int i=0;i<(a.L<b.L?a.L:b.L);++i)c+=(a[i]-32)*(b[i]-32)%95+32;return c;}
```

If the first version uses a lambda, it's because i wanted to test C++11 std::async function i just learnt before, so i kept it for no reasons...

More readable version :

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

#define L length()
#define S string

//Function code for the original version
S m(S a,S b) {
    S c;
    int m = a.L < b.L ? a.L : b.L;

    auto l=[m](S&s){
        s = s.substr(0, m);
        for_each(s.begin(),s.end(),[](char&c){
            c -= 32;
        });
    };
    l(a);
    l(b);
    for(int i=0;i<m;++i) {
        c += a[i] * b[i] % 95 + 32;
    }
    return c;
}

//Code for the version 2
S m2(S a,S b) {
    S c;
    for(int i = 0; i < (a.L < b.L ? a.L : b.L); ++i) {
        c += (a[i] - 32) * (b[i] - 32) % 95 + 32;
    }
    return c;
}

int main() {
    string a, b, c;
    getline(cin, a);
    getline(cin, b);
    c = m(a, b);
    cout << c;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it. I have no experience in golfing with C++, but [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132/tips-for-golfing-in-c) you'll find some tips. Enjoy your time here!

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure you can just submit a function, like [this](https://tio.run/##TY9BbsMgEEX3nGLUqBHUjhW16qLFTpfd5AZRVA2Y2EgGIoNVVZHPno4dqymL4fOYz3z0@bxptL6urNfdUBsobYipN@h2/xgR65sduxPsmtDb1LodGyLdgUdn4hm1gZhqyVa1OVlvYA@d8U1qufhDn9CY1JHi2np2exocXwTmsCglLovS0voEruJY7EtV7MUHiXcSEocUoKsO7rj415FcVSzioAjwbe6EPIX@y6BueSyUaaznIo@F8TXthyPXLfZrLS56U708y1HIUXYcBRU1W/k021ZbaUsns8xSZ1bhwR6fFJXHt9dssvUmDb2npON1zorTGLgwBrTuX1M5tcCNIlTw0A6@6X8e5EzURL5DqOk8A03AccwpyQLCkMpSSzZefwE).

Comment: Can't you remove the spaces here: `#include <string>`=>`#include<string>` and `#include <algorithm>`=>`#include<algorithm>`?

Comment: In addition you should be able to create a macro equivalent to `string` and use it accordingly.

Comment: `(a.L<b.L)`=>`a.L<b.L`.

Comment: Also, on the second solution, is algorithm even needed? In addition, on the second solution, I don't think the braces are needed after the for loop.

Comment: Would it be possible to use `using S=std::string;` like I see you do in your more recent answers?

Comment: @Zacharý yeah, but it just saves one byte

Comment: (I think two if you remove the newline)

Answer (score 3):

## Dyalog APL, <s>36</s> <s>34</s> <s>33</s> <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
{⎕UCS 32+95|×⌿32-⎕UCS↑⍵}
```

[Try it online (TryAPL)!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%u2395UCS%2032+95%7C%D7%u233F32-%u2395UCS%u2191%u2375%7D%27split%27%20%27isbn%27&run)

[Try it online (TIO)!](https://tio.run/##Tc@xTsMwEAbgPU9x7WIk1KUtAwxdGBBDpgqJrUpqK7V0tYNzFgrQtRNFdEA8CQsLA2/iFwl26UW9xefv/pPsosaRbAu0VdetPdIibN@fw9vH3fUcJuPzy4uX38/w@jMZj/4xbPdh97XJUjZFDzsQdt9Ju07opjQCkoJoatQkMsH3k/YWpDVCEKwLIuXiBE6LY7kCozStlIOrsxgqPUFaHXBgwBWHD96SangyPFTkR2sl48qbyrURyRUtY/Wk60jaSN@Q67m0RkaufYl6yUgWMaJLx5FkCpiIN/f9s1KbiSkgIkwZ@ZqJfDbL@y@m/g8)

Input is a list of strings, and has trailing whitespace.

Here's how it works:

```
{⎕UCS 32+95|×⌿32-⎕UCS↑⍵}
                     ↑⍵ - the input as a 2d array
                 ⎕UCS   - codepoints
              32-       - subtract 32
            ×⌿          - element wise product reduction ([a,b]=>a×b)
         95|            - Modulo 95
      32+               - Add 32
 ⎕UCS                   - Unicode characters
```

Comment: I didn't get the interface of `tryapl.org`, so [here](https://tio.run/##Tc@xTsMwEAbgPU9xZTFSVVVqywBDFwbEkKlCYk1wlFo67ODYQikwIVWiIggGxM7UF2BhpG/iFwlnxEW9xfd/d7LsrMKRbDI0Zddde3Rh/XoXNo/h5f3idPGznU6Gx0f3u4/xdDIK7ZY5tN@h/QrrNzJKz5txePpkfug6oepcC4gXgqgrVE4kgjO1sF/saQG6UG5ZWDg5pKXcOzgHaQa8MOCi4Y03rqh5cvBXxLfGSMal16VtCJ3NGsZypSoipaWvne05N1oSVz5HdcXoDCKhjcc/ybigCc8u@2fFNhEzQESYMXJMRDqfp/0XY/8L "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")'s a TIO for those that want to try it.

Comment: There, I put both in there.

Answer (score 3):

## FSharp 275 bytes

```
let f (p : string, q : string) =     
let l = if p.Length < q.Length then p.Length else q.Length
p.Substring(0,l).ToCharArray() |> Array.mapi (fun i x -> (((int(x) - 32) * (int(q.[i]) - 32)) % 95) + 32) |> Array.map (fun x -> char(x).ToString()) |> Array.fold(+) ""
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: [169 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY7BisIwEIbvPsUQEDLahkXZg8IWFq/e3Jt6qKtpB9pJmqSsiu/eTat40jl9w//xz2if1oZN11WnAFrapQ@OuEiaB@CXVZv2cF/kR1ITg1XrExehhOYBqH7Mqszdt3P5ReItG0DVuSWpWwaCc5r9RkHGIQ7yjOl8hpOBG7Wl/bDjePGJ0wixbnM/iM8ybaqjnKIQnQYpRAJCINwysNELGsTY71iM@oz8gfvc24rCO6lsuXCXXvsz5vjOKq5keyfED1443T8)

Comment: [127 bytes](https://tio.run/##dcxBDoIwFATQvaf4aUJoFYjRuNBETuCOpboApeUn8Cm0RDDcHQVZym4m8zLS@EVJ5TDkqQXJ9cnYGkl51RzEWQdRk/wK33oFEujgkpKyGVRzEH0YTSAoYo1cNgQIrR8@srjmnCNZ3gp/vxPrKVfBFe9TF87xIDYuuGKQwBnzgDEBfQj6@2YlMMfciK3GDU1C4250jnYJZQ2puhvZqyyfS0q9UY/G1nH3xwwf)

Comment: [126 bytes](https://tio.run/##dcxBDoIwEAXQvaeYNCFpFYjRuNBETuCOpboApTAJDIWWCIa7V4ssZTX/57@M1EFVU21tmRmQXJ20aZFyv5mDOKsw7tJf4Vu/QgIVXjLKTQHNHMQYxRMIq0Qhlx0BQh9EjyJpOedIhvci2O/EespNeMX71IV3PGzctRI4Yz4wJmCMQH2fGQnM0zdiK7ehTsntWpVollDRUd4Ojr3q@rmk8jcqZ0ybDH@M/QA)

Comment: [124 bytes](https://tio.run/##dYxBDoIwEEX3nmLShKRVIEbjQhM5gTuW6gKUwiQwLbREMdwdKbKU1byX/zLSBJUiNQxlZkFyfTK2Qcr9egZx1mHcpj/hW79CAh1eMsptAfUMoo/iKQirRCOXLQHCO4geRdJwzpHsaPudWE9Yh1e8OxXe8bBxd5DAGfOBMQF9BHp8ZSUwz9yIrdyGJiW3G12iXYqKlvKmc9lLqedSlX9Qu8Y2SfenGb4)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
.BÇ32-`*₃%32+çJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fz@lwu7GRboLWo6ZmVWMj7cPLvf7/j1YvLsjJLEkuSqyqzElMyUwtzk3MTs1NBQlkphap66hnFiflqcdyAQA)

-1 for Emigna pointing out `₃` pushes `95`.

---

```
                 # ['hi', 'you']
.B               # [['hi ', 'you']]
  Ç              # [[[104, 105, 32], [121, 111, 117]]]
   32-           # [[[72, 73, 0], [89, 79, 85]]]
      `          # [[72, 73, 0], [89, 79, 85]]
       *         # [[6408, 5767, 0]]
        ₃%       # [[43, 67, 0]]
          32+    # [[75, 99, 32]]
             ç   # [['K', 'c', ' ']]
              J  # ['Kc ']
```

---

```
.BÇ32-`*95%žQsèJ
```

is another.

Comment: `₃` saves a byte. Too bad about the empty string input. Otherwise `ø` would save a few more.

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 23 bytes

```
{z{2' e]' f-:*95%' +}%}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/uqraSF0hNVZdIU3XSsvSVFVdQbtWtfZ/3f9opeKCnMwSJQWlzOKkPKVYAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform),<strike>100 96</strike> 95 bytes

```cs
(l,n)=>{for(int i=0;i<l.Length&i<n.Length;)Console.Write((char)((l[i]-32)*(n[i++]-32)%95+32));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BSsRAEETv8xVNQOkx2SDKHmSSBfGqB9mDh8VDdhyThrFHpltBQr49G7Nal1dUQVFeNj7lMH8JcQ/7H9Hw4YzxsROBZzMaWCTaKXn4TvQGTx0x2jU@l7@690qJG9G8rFRw5g56aGHGWLFtd@N7ykisQO21oybWj4F7HS6p4T/r7ENiSTHUL5k0IPqhyxYxHuh1c3tjr5APVJarv7jblgusm@bl7f@NHgv5jKRFVZAcubBurSYzzSc)

-4 bytes thanks to @Zacharý

-1 byte by moving the increment

Uses a lambda and abuses the fact that characters are basically ints.

Comment: Can you use `(l[i]-32)*(n[i]-32)%95+32`?

Comment: Why yes, I can. Thanks!

Comment: You need to fully qualify the `Console` and you can use currying to save a byte. Compile to a `Action<string, Action<string>>` like `l=>n=>` and call like `("word")("string")`

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 114 bytes

```
(a=Min@StringLength[x={##}];FromCharacterCode[Mod[Times@@(#-32&/@ToCharacterCode/@(StringTake[#,a]&/@x)),95]+32])&
```

**input**

> ["public","toll"]

Comment: Is there a way to try it online?

Comment: of course, go to https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/ paste the code, paste input at the end, press shift+enter

Comment: what "8 chars"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! The message "Thanks!" would have been too short to post just like this, it needed 8 chars more.

Comment: ok....................................

Answer (score 2):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 52 bytes

```
[,:$#'"!MIN$take"![CS#.toarr]"!32-prod 95%32+#:''#`]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZExT8MwEIX3/opLUnSJ2magZcBDhcSAOoSFBalUIqnd1qqJjXMWKn8@JIU2ccSTPPjpe3enu4ry7VHwul5P2TjCMMhWz2PKjyIM1o8vUUo6t3YTBvPbmbGaw/3dzfx2EjHE6H1TP7DdaBTH8CesjJKE0BPKqigxGUEMnu1Bv85/EK6A6xKR4CMnEvYM@dn2h5mAUkg6CAssvlbCwhG0FYJLBIOL@u3w02kSVa8uhmf5M@GX1rwPHVy5t6cBRDY/@SvYf0vTQShL7iqyA6jQJfdmMq5QcutDpJUatLOt1UN4GxtuHJ9eg8HWWqeDcAFKKVh00NXx22XLZebPdHaSBNbAIE1T2MEUNs25DMQx5s0Ji@ZpR8YRJs3xZp2QsSb4BpMJcFmZ@gc)

Function that takes two arguments from the stack.

### Explanation

```
[,:$#'"!MIN$take"![CS#.toarr]"!32-prod 95%32+#:''#`]
```

Let's look at the first part, assuming the top two items are `'split'` and `'isbn'`:

```
,:$#'"!MIN$take"!      stack:                      ('split' 'isbn')
,                      pair top two:               (('split' 'isbn'))
 :                     duplicate:                  (('split' 'isbn') ('split' 'isbn'))
  $#'                  length function literal:    (('split' 'isbn') ('split' 'isbn') $#')
    "!                 execute on each:            (('split' 'isbn') (5 4))
      MIN              obtain the minimum:         (('split' 'isbn') 4)
         $take         "take" function literal:    (('split' 'isbn') 4 $take)
                       (e.g. `'asdf' 2 take` is `'as'`)
              "!       vectorized binary each:     (('spli' 'isbn'))
```

This part performs the cropping.

Then:

```
[CS#.toarr]"!     stack: (('spli' 'isbn'))
[         ]"!     perform the inside on each string
                  string `'spli'`:
 CS               convert to a character string:    $'spli'
   #.             vectorized "ord":                 (115 112 108 105)
     toarr        convert to array:                 (115 112 108 105)
                  (needed for empty string, since `$'' #.` == `$''` not `()`
```

Then, the last part:

```
32-prod 95%32+#:''#`  stack: (((115 112 108 105) (105 115  98 110)))
32-                   subtract 32 from each character code:   (((83 80 76 73) (73 83 66 78)))
   prod               reduce multiplication over the array:   ((6059 6640 5016 5694))
        95%           modulus 95:                             ((74 85 76 89))
           32+        add 32:                                 ((106 117 108 121))
              #:      convert to characters:                  (('j' 'u' 'l' 'y'))
                ''#`  join:                                   ('july')
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 88 bytes

```r
function(r,s,u=utf8ToInt)intToUtf8((((u(r)-32)*(u(s)-32))%%95+32)[0:min(nchar(c(r,s)))])
```

anonymous function; takes input as two strings; third argument is just to ensure this is a one line function and save some bytes.

The TIO link below returns an array with entries named with the first input.

[Try all test cases!](https://tio.run/##ZY5BSwMxEIXv/oo0UJLUFERb0FJ7lR56qyCIh93NbjeQncRkgqx/fp1sEQQfgffNMJl5cerYfj11GRq0HmTUSefnjN3j2R8BlQU8@1cqJSnLqNYP92pFlGZSy@XT9pbg/W43WJDQ9FWUTVmjlPpQ01CF4EbZ6UZym2rgml8f@yOuGa8zMsuMX1AhPrPHNglqf3lvaBpjNZJZMDlhLBhy7WxDEL1zZC9v9JNvmHOObcrC0@Fw4krf0OEUnMXr2SOdAIFsqBDbOM@1DFqLfRvZTpbG4lclCZ8ltOgzXOJIcPm2gaz2YMiQrpOZkgYIKEaJ/S@Hmn4A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 65 bytes

64 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
$n=reverse<>;s/./($_=chop$n)&&chr 32+(-32+ord$&)*(-32+ord)%95/ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r6xYAKQVdAv@q@TZFqWWpRYVp9rYWRfr6@lrqMTbJmfkF6jkaaqpJWcUKRgbaWvoAon8ohQVNU0tGFtT1dJUPz31/39fOztfLhABAA)

Answer (score 2):

## D, 113 bytes

```d
T m(T)(T a,T b){T c;for(int i;i<(a.length<b.length?a.length:b.length);++i)c~=(a[i]-32)*(b[i]-32)%95+32;return c;}
```

This is a port of [HatsuPointerKun's C++ solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133871/55550), don't forget to upvote them!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ncy9DoIwFIbhmV5FF9NTQQaIgxbjTXQjDOVHPQm0pFQdCN56rQaGJ3nzneS03ks6gOQgqUokrfksaSNuxgJqR1FgASrtO313j6Je47ot523hIo6RN58LqBKrQ57xPdRr7U7HOM@E7dzT6vB7IS@DLR0UauB0JhEOo7GOTq5NAzSCRG@Lrus1DFCyiSVsDPoAA8eqpPzX71IHmlWcC7J4/wU)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>127</s> <s>115</s> <s>97</s> 95 bytes

```java
a->b->{for(int i=0;i<a.length&i<b.length;System.out.printf("%c",(a[i]-32)*(b[i++]-32)%95+32));}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##tZNfS8MwFMXf9ymuhWnqXBD/PGi3ggiKD3vaizD3kKbZlpklNblR5thnn5lWEVlAiqaFXjg3v3Mu9M7ZM@uaSuh5@bjhijkHAyb1qgXgkKHkMA8d1KNUdOI1R2k0vamLHp8xOxof7eq5Ntr5hbB1T54Dhz5sWDcvuvlqYiyRGkH2jzPZY1QJPcXZvuwVdZkNlw7FghqPtLKhdUKSNk@OCBvJcff0JD0kxUh2Ou91@@K8Ez5ptt5kIXh4K1@okL0e4dnIEhZhLDLEwJqOxsDS7YgAnLKqUkuSuEpJTCia65D3ylq2JGlKGeeiQpJIV@ifYvYO@JlTaVIrX@go9e@Jd1AafYBhWERhG/Ph@4maDQRoIXEmLFySxl6FR9jG3ov67H2exh5P3qBwUYOHb09jjxdjyqjDzOupXTZmY@iPsqevsmpMlrr0Dm2cjkapxvSPNfyf5HZHsC9yuTVuvrG39/G/cYf2a@4ZKKXgLMqO6L/mD/J8EF/XHeL2/rq13rwB)

```java
a->b->{                       // Method with 2 char-array parameters and no return-type
  for(int i=0;                //  Index-integer, starting at 0
      i<a.length&i<b.length;  //  Loop over both arrays up to the smallest of the two
    System.out.printf("%c",   //   Print, as character:
      (a[i]-32)               //    Current char of `a` minus 32
      *(b[i++]-32)            //    multiplied with current char of `b` minus 32
      %95                     //    Take modulo-95 of that multiplied result
      +32));}                 //    And add 32 again
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 166 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;s=>t=>{int e=s.Length,n=t.Length,l=e>n?n:e;return string.Concat(s.Substring(0,l).Select((c,i)=>(char)((((c-32)*(t.Substring(0,l)[i]-32))%95)+32)));}
```

I'm sure there's a lot of golfing to be done but I don't have time right now.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDBTsMwDL3nK6JKSAl0EQJxgJJwQOI0JEQPHBCHLPO2SJkLtYuEpn57SVcmMXgX2@/52bIDzbYNNkNHEdey/iKGbSV@V2Ye8aMSIiRPJJ/ETsgMYs8xyM8mLuWjj6j0np7EEQ8dhlviNg8qj4spOidX0sqBrGPrdhFZgiUzB1zzpkTLhzRZcHiHN1C1wF2LP35z32DwrMjU3WKi1HmZtKkhQWClQhm1dSpsfKtVRphdXuhTxX/6X@PbKOiT6yt9Nia66od87uGOvIaaBOaljQz5FaCO969UQe8pcqFVEWmBxTjhv/0Z/HLvzuLI96IfvgE)

Full/Formatted Version:

```c#
using System;
using System.Linq;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Func<string, Func<string, string>> f = s => t =>
        {
            int e = s.Length, n = t.Length, l = e > n ? n : e;

            return string.Concat(s.Substring(0, l).Select((c, i) => (char)((((c - 32) * (t.Substring(0, l)[i] - 32)) % 95) + 32)));
        };

        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(f("split")("isbn")));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `(((c-32)*(t.Substring(0,l)[i]-32))%95)+32)` can be `((c-32)*(t.Substring(0,l)[i]-32)%95+32)` (might have screwed up the parens there ... it's looking like lisp!)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>95</s> 73 bytes

- Thanks @Zacharý for 4 bytes: unwanted brackets removed

```python
lambda x,y:''.join(chr((ord(i)-32)*(ord(j)-32)%95+32)for i,j in zip(x,y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcsxDsIwDEDRq3hBtiEwFDGAxE1YWqKojsCO3CARLh@qTv8tv7Q6mw493R/9Nb6nOMI3tBviKZsoPWcnMo8kfDwPvN@cN@@ul8OaZA4SMojCTwqtM3MvLlohEU6mEQOKxs9SvSH3Pw)

Comment: Goodness gracious ... learn to use order of operations!
`(((ord(x[i])-32)*(ord(y[i])-32))%95)+32` => `(ord(x[i])-32)*(ord(y[i])-32)%95+32`

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 99 bytes

```
(lambda(a b)(map'string(lambda(x y)(code-char(+(mod(*(-(#1=char-code x)32)(-(#1#y)32))95)32)))a b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcxBCoMwFATQq3ziwvmWLKp00YWH@SZFBWNCtNScPjWCqxnewJhl3kJGiPO6EzIWcYMVCA0MJ6He9nMZbz4oMYy3H20miXjAeYsGGtWzL6LLRgd3LV9YpVL5/bqCyytn9fPeKlLTdx1jUqf8AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 24 bytes

```
¬íVq)®®©c -HÃ×u95 +H dÃq
```

Returns a string with trailing null-chars (`\u0000`) when the first input is longer than the second.

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=rO1WcSmurqljIC1Iw9d1OTUgK0ggZMNx&input=InNwbGl0IgoiaXNibiIKLVE=) with the `-Q` flag to show formatted output, including the null-chars.

[Run all the test cases](https://codepen.io/justinm53/full/NvKjZr?code=rO1WcSmurqljIC1Iw9d1OTUgK0ggZMNx&inputs=ImlzYm4iCiJzcGxpdCI=,IiIKIiI=,IiIKIkkgZG9uJ3QgbWF0dGVyIg==,IiAgICAgICAgICAgICAiCiJNZSBuZWl0aGVyIDooIg==,ImJ1dCBJIGRvISIKIiEhISEhISEhISI=,J3F1b3RlcycKJyIiIiIiIic=,Indvb2QiCiJodW5ncnki,InRyYXkiCiJnemlwIg==,ImluZHVzdHJ5IgoiYm9uZCI=,InB1YmxpYyIKInRvbGwi,InJvbGwiCiJkdWJsaW4i,IkdYISIKIkdYISI=,IjQgbGxsIDQiCiI0IGxsbCA0Ig==,Ik0+Pk0iCiJNPj5NIg==&flags=LVE=) using my WIP CodePen.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 30 bytes

```
Ｆ⌊⟦ＬθＬη⟧℅⁺³²﹪×⁻³²℅§θι⁻³²℅§ηι⁹⁵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYy7CgIxFER7vyLlDWQbxUKsxEpwcQs7sQhJ3ASSXDYPH19/zeK2VjMMZ46yMimUnuiBiUHvogs1wO1s4lgsTFywpVp@55wNycUCx/aSqpgEg68ZNmvBetTVI1xdMHnWLPMlaRelh0M5RW3eMAnmOG/W/4j9IY3ZbefcE70Q9crWOKYPdU/qsv8C) Link is to verbose version of code. I actually wrote the calcualation as `(32 - ord(q)) * (32 - ord(h))` because it avoids consecutive numeric literals but I guess I could have just written `(ord(q) - ord(" ")) * (ord(h) - ord(" "))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 95 bytes

```perl
@a=<>=~/(.)/g;@b=<>=~/(.)/g;$#a=$#b if@a>@b;print chr 32+(-32+ord$_)*(-32+ord$b[$i++])%95 for@a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/98h0dbGzrZOX0NPUz/d2iEJmaeinGiropykkJnmkGjnkGRdUJSZV6KQnFGkYGykraELJPKLUlTiNbXg7KRolUxt7VhNVUtThbT8IofE//8zi5PyuIoLcjJLAA)

**Explanation:**

```perl
@a=<>=~/(.)/g;@b=<>=~/(.)/g;  # Split the strings into 2 arrays
$#a=$#b if@a>@b;              # Truncate the first if longer than the second
print chr 32+(-32+ord$_)*(-32+ord$b[$i++])%95 for@a  # Multiply each character
```

Comment: I think you're not correctly truncating the result to the length of the smaller string (see [here](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gtDjDIVEnWl9DT1M/PTYtv0ihOL@oxMbOOjexoLqgKDOvRCE5o0jB2EhbQxdI5BelqMRrasHZidGGsdEqmdrasZqqlqa1DtVAEYPY2v//i4uT8rgyC3IySwA)).

Comment: You're right.  Fixed it at a cost of many bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 19 bytes

```
(PA$* *(PA@?Zg)%95)
```

Takes the strings as command-line arguments. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fI8BRRUtBC0g52Eela6pammr@//@/uCAns@R/ZnFSHgA)

#### Explanation

```
(PA$* *(PA@?Zg)%95)
                     g is list of args; PA is string of all printable ASCII characters
            Zg       Zip items of g together: result is list of pairs of characters
        PA@?         Find index of each character in PA
       (      )      (Parentheses to get correct operator precedence)
   $* *              Map (fold on *) to the list: multiplies each pair of numbers
               %95   Take list items mod 95
(PA               )  Use those numbers to index into PA again
                     Print the resulting list of chars, concatenated together (implicit)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](http://factorcode.org), 45

```
[ [ [ 32 - ] bi@ * 95 mod 32 + ] "" 2map-as ]
```

It's a quotation (lambda), `call` it with two strings on the stack, leaves the new string on the stack.

As a word:

```
: s* ( s1 s2 -- ps ) [ [ 32 - ] bi@ * 95 mod 32 + ] "" 2map-as ;

"M>>M" "M>>M" s*      ! => ">MM>"
dup s*                ! => "M>>M"
dup s*                ! => ">MM>"
...
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 26 bytes

**Solution:**

```
`c$32+95!*/-32+(&/#:'x)$x:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/PyFZxdhI29JUUUtfF8jQUNNXtlKv0FSpsNJQysxLKS0uKapUslZKys9LUdL8/x8A)

**Example:**

```
`c$32+95!*/-32+(&/#:'x)$x:("split";"isbn")
"july"
```

**Explanation:**

Evaluation is performed right-to-left:

```
`c$32+95!*/-32+(&/#:'x)$x: / the solution
                        x: / assign input to variable x
                       $   / pad right to length on left
               (  #:'x)    / count each x (return length of each char list in list)
                &/         / min-over, get the minimum of these counts
           -32+            / subtract 32, this automagically converts chars -> ints
         */                / multiply-over, product of the two lists
      95!                  / modulo 95
   32+                     / add 32 back again
`c$                        / convert to character array
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 65 bytes

```
{zip(it){a,b->(a-' ')*(b-' ')%95+32}.fold(""){s,i->s+i.toChar()}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY69DoIwFIV3nuKGxHArlEHjIAk4uLr5BG0AvbEUQouDTZ@91p@4eZaTnG843220inS4CwXDoio425n0pcRPM@DNd4I6uAdNSJY5UUjeoOAZZGyN8t2r/S7fbnzZj6rFNGXOFMQbk1Npx@NVzMi8D/2iYRCkkYFLIOb1K6CGuRPtiXQXwaGCNP1B@Q9OUcpidMZow1jiAxmpEzMpsk8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 39 bytes

```
[ [ [ 32 - ] bi@ * 95 mod 32 + ] 2map ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY4xC8IwFIR3f8WRRVB0qDioIG7SxUWcpEOaPjHYJjHvOUjpb4@J3PR93ME9tBEf0@1aX857aGZvGC@KjnoMWp4IkUS@IVonYHp/yBliHGYjRijLrVNQHHorClNRGWt03s2l7IVi8VO6o2RTYYUGrT1hgd0Wg@@KW2ZXDTqgSWNu/18cC6/TDw)

### Explanation:

This is a quotation (anonymous function) that takes two strings from the data stack and leaves one string on the data stack. In Factor, strings are just sequences of unicode code points and can be manipulated like any other sequence.

- Assuming a data stack that looks like `"split" "isbn"` when this function is called...
- `[ [ 32 - ] bi@ * 95 mod 32 + ]` push a quotation to the data stack (to be used later by `2map`) `"split" "isbn" [ [ 32 - ] bi@ * 95 mod 32 + ]`
- `2map` map over two sequences, combining them into one sequence with the given quotation which has stack effect `( x x -- x )`.
- At the beginning of the first iteration of `2map`, the data stack looks like this: `115 105`
- `[ 32 - ]` push a quotation to the data stack to be used later by the word `bi@`. `115 105 [ 32 - ]`
- `bi@` apply a quotation to the object on top of the data stack *and* the second-top object on the data stack `83 73`
- `*` multiply top two objects on the data stack `6059`
- `95` push `95` to the data stack `6059 95`
- `mod` reduce NOS (next on stack) modulo TOS (top of stack) `74`
- `32` push `32` to the data stack `74 32`
- `+` add top two objects on the data stack `106`
- So, at the end of the quotation to `2map`, we are left with `106`, which is the code point for `'j'`, which is the first element of the output sequence. The quotation given to `2map` will be run on each pair of elements until one of the two sequences no longer has any elements, meaning the output sequence will have the same size as the shorter of the two input sequences.

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 81 bytes

```red
func[a b][repeat i min length? a length? b[prin a/:i - 32 *(b/:i - 32)% 95 + 32]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T@tNC85OlEhKTa6KLUgNbFEIVMhNzNPISc1L70kw14hEc5Kii4oAkok6ltlKugqGBspaGkkwdiaqgqWpgraQFZs7P80BaXigpzMEiUFpczipDyl/wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md), 11 bytes

`32â-R*95%+¥`

Takes input as an array of 2 strings

prints additional trailing spaces if one string is longer

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=MzLiLVIqOTUlK6U=&in=WyJpc2JuIiwgInNwbGl0Il0=)

### Explanation

```
32â-R*95%+¥ ; implicit input
32          ; constant 32
  â         ; push 32 below implicit input
   -        ; subtract 32 from input
    R*      ; multiply elements of input array
      95%   ; take input modulo 95
         +  ; add 32
          ¥ ; print value as string (implicit output will print '()' for empty string)
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 112 bytes

```
for($i=0;$i<min(strlen($a=$argv[1]),strlen($b=$argv[2]));$i++)echo chr((ord($a[$i])-32)*(ord($b[$i])-32)%95+32);
```

Comment: **109 bytes:** `for($i=0;$i<strlen($a=$argv[1])&&$i<strlen($b=$argv[2]);)echo chr((ord($a[$i])-32)*(ord($b[$i++])-32)%95+32);` Also, I'm not entirely sure if replacing `&&` with `&` might also be possible in PHP, reducing it by another byte to **108**.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 89 bytes

Javascript and the curse of the lengthy function names ...

Using currying and the fact that `charCodeAt` returns `NaN` when called with an invalid position. There can be trailing nulls in the output.

```
a=>b=>a.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>String.fromCharCode((z=x=>x.charCodeAt(i)-32)(a)*z(b)%95+32))
```

**Test**

```js
var f=
a=>b=>a.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>String.fromCharCode((z=x=>x.charCodeAt(i)-32)(a)*z(b)%95+32))

q=x=>'['+x+']'

;[["isbn", "split"],["", ""],["", "I don't matter"],["             ", "Me neither :("],
["but I do!", "!!!!!!!!!"],['quotes', '""""""'],["wood", "hungry"],["tray", "gzip"],
["industry", "bond"],["public", "toll"],["roll", "dublin"],["GX!", "GX!"],
["4 lll 4", "4 lll 4"],["M>>M", "M>>M"]]
.forEach(([a,b])=>console.log(q(a)+' x '+q(b)+' --> '+q(f(a)(b))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 16 bytes

```
øŀC32-ƒ*95%32+Cṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDuMWAQzMyLcaSKjk1JTMyK0PhuYUiLCIiLCJbXCJ3b29kXCIsIFwiaHVuZ3J5XCJdIl0=)

```
øŀC32-ƒ*95%32+Cṅ  # Example input: ["wood", "hungry"]
øŀ                # Align to left by padding to the right with spaces: ["wood  ", "hungry"]
  C               # Character codes: [[119, 111, 111, 100, 32, 32], [104, 117, 110, 103, 114, 121]]
   32-            # Subtract 32: [[87, 79, 79, 68, 0, 0], [72, 85, 78, 71, 82, 89]]
      ƒ*          # Element-wise multiply both: [6264, 6715, 6162, 4828, 0, 0]
        95%       # Modulo 95: [89, 65, 82, 78, 0, 0]
           32+    # Add 32: [121, 97, 114, 110, 32, 32]
              C   # From character codes: ["y", "a", "r", "n", " ", " "]
               ṅ  # Join together: "yarn  "
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 88 bytes

```ruby
->a{c,d=a.map{_1[0,a.map(&:size).min].bytes}
c.map{((_1-32)*(d.shift-32)%95+32).chr}*""}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3I3TtEquTdVJsE_VyEwuq4w2jDXTATA01q-LMqlRNvdzMvFi9pMqS1OJarmSwIg2NeENdYyNNLY0UveKMzLQSEEfV0lQbSOklZxTVaikp1ULM31FQWlKs4BYdrVRckJNZoqSjlFmclKcUGwuRXrAAQgMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `B`, 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Z32-€p95%32+
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#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)

##### Explanation

```python
Z32-€p95%32+  # Implicit input (converted to ordinals)
Z             # Zip them together (truncate longer one)
 32-          # Subtract 32 (vectorised)
    €p        # Product of each inner pair
      95%     # Modulo by 95 (vectorised)
         32+  # Add 32 (vectorised)
              # Implicit output (converted to string)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 82 bytes

```bash
s=
repeat $#1 ((#2))&&s+=${(#)$((32+(#1-32)*(#2-32)%95))}&&1=${1:1} 2=${2:1}
<<<$s
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZPBbtNAEIYP3OYpphs33m3jg90iQZpYVKKgiloC0gMSipAdb2KDsdPdtUJc-Ul6iYS48EbwNOzatVCImYNnPPPtv7Pj9cP3Sia7n0vKqOQKnW8_SrV0nv16L6cg-JqHCq2Bi5QOPMaGQ3k6te7pgFmUnnmndOA6Zx470UXjj58_ZaweDl3NuGO3Rk8Hng5gMplYslX-_cRisEnSjKPgYYyOwCzN-QXGBcCmELGcUqL3ePGO6WfFTLGuCQMxtegSrfuG-ejOj0c1Wu2LN2ewCCVHS2CaA5DHvOPOCTLki6TAt5ez2dVLtJrNLuBE5ztr6q8ur2-6Oo61EgCX4QIgLnRiMrFvr2a3NpBURjkZIZHrLFUED8zxkXwusy0BYrAeYg99xK718XNb4ddQKS5IH7aXM2sCjjlPVcIFjilpsH0GSFQqNNJHhj_qjOxJ_2XAvisLxaU9Qps0Zh92bC--fErfrPQkNkURG92kzFdie3hQI74NRa77UCLcGnRVpeu-iTRDC6tKo2kel1KJBo-KPP4XN2gsirVG12WUpQsDqiLL-htYhroCRBhAg7FZkvejUYu-_tBMy7ieTlvUDBHIOWZZhueG7sIDsisACXw_aD6b8f_R9YPAJ2BuWvuz7Hat_wM)

The flags needed to emulate `zip()` added too many characters, so we instead repeat for the length of the first argument, and check `((#2))` to see if we've reached the end of the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 62 bytes

```
map(explode)|transpose|map((.[0]-32)*(.[1]-32)%95?+32)|implode
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZDNTsMwDMfFlSNPkEVCdLAhPoYEHMoRcegdqfTQkrAFpUnWOIKhvgmXComHgqfB9qg0R4rt39-24nx-va6H4TvBy_z6J2_rkOn3YL3S0x662sXgo-4JZ6flWTW_vJgeY3TO0eHN1d0J-t603LKd8j9s-N07KKWJjZMzGYM1IKv9UmIy-gehvDsC0dYAumMqdg1LCi2cNrDSnbjNuKJJIKhxgupkNFbWyYOOiJ92Ditv3ivkq-SW3YYJrrZBsvwwgXPjVIrQEWu8U8xCaqx5RgLeWiYdBTOpSHBM7h_pHXRTthDWWrFAMkZEizwvaBVy1fZv_gA)

`transpose` fills in `null` for missing elements, we suppress those with `?`.