# Take the square root of a string

Tags: code-golf, string, printable-ascii

#### Motivation

In [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133767/element-wise-string-multiplication) challenge your task was to multiply two strings, this naturally introduces a way to take the square root of a string.

#### How does it work?

Given a string (for example `pub`) the first thing you need to do, is to determine the [ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) for each character:

```
"pub" -> [112, 117, 98]
```

Next you map these codes to the range `[0..94]` by subtracting `32` of each value:

```
[112, 117, 98] -> [80, 85, 66]
```

Now you need to find for each value its root modulo `95` (eg. `40*40 % 95 = 80`, you could also pick `55`):

```
[80, 85, 66] -> [40, 35, 16]
```

And finally you'll map it back to the range `[32..126]` and convert it back to a string:

```
[40, 35, 16] -> [72, 67, 48] -> "HC0"
```

Indeed `"HC0" ⊗ "HC0" = "pub"` as you can verify with a solution from the other challenge [here](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P9nYSLfA0jTG2Eg7@f//anUPZwN1HQUwVQsA).

---

The ones familiar with [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n) probably noticed that the square root modulo `95` does not always exist, for example there's no root for `2`. In such a case the square root of a string is not defined and your program/function may crash, loop indefinetly etc.

For your convenience, here's the list of chars that have a square root (the first one is a space):

```
 !$%&)+03489:>CDGLMQVW]`bjlpqu
```

#### Rules

- You will write a program/function that takes a string (or list of chars) as an argument and returns *any* square root if it exists
- You may assume that the input always has a square root
- The input may consist of an empty string
- The input will be in the printable range (`[32..126]`)
- The output is either printed to the console or you return a string if the square root exists
- In case the square root doesn't exist, the behavior of your program/function is left undefined
- If you choose to print the root to the console trailing newlines or whitespaces are fine

#### Test cases

Note that these are not necessarily the only solutions:

```
''              -> ''
'pub'           -> 'HC0'
'pull!'         -> 'HC33!'
'M>>M'          -> '>MM>'
'49'            -> '4%'
'64'            -> undefined
'Hello, World!' -> undefined
```

Comment: Forcing an error state on these characters without a square root seems unnecessary, I'd recommend just undefined behavior.

Comment: @ATaco I updated the challenge.

Comment: What to do if the given string is the square of multiple strings?

Comment: @tsh Return any, I'll update the challenge.

Comment: @Downvoter Why the downvote?

Comment: Is it deliberate that you map to the range 0-95 and then take modulo 95 instead of 96?

Comment: @curiousdannii Actually it should be the range `0-94` (that's the printable range), that's a typo - sorry about that.

Comment: Can the output be a list of chars?

Comment: @Oliver Yes, it can.

Answer (score 10):

## sh + coreutils, 58 bytes

```bash
tr '$%&)+0389:>CDGLMQVW]`bjpqu' 1u.#:BFO%+M/L2Aa,795d0@H=C
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6RIQV1FVU1T28DYwtLKztnF3cc3MCw8NiEpq6CwVF3BsFRP2crJzV9V21ffx8gxUcfc0jTFwMHD1vn/f66C0iQgzslR5PK1s/PlMrEEAA)

The modular square root is typically not unique; we have 2 or 4 choices for each character except .  We don’t need to translate , `!`, `4`, `l` since each is already a square root of itself.  For the remaining characters, we choose images that don’t need to be escaped for the shell or `tr`.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3, <s>57</s> 56 bytes

```
lambda s:s.translate({k*k%95+32:k+32for k in range(95)})
```

`translate` uses a mapping from "Unicode ordinals to Unicode ordinals". Thus, we don't need `chr`/`ord` conversions. Note: it doesn't crash when the char has no root.

Saved 1 byte thanks to @jonathan-allan

The value of the mapping is the greatest root in range 0..94 of the key. To have the least root (as in the examples), use:

```
lambda s:s.translate({k*k%95+32:k+32for k in range(95,0,-1)})
```

(61 bytes)

```
>>> [s.translate({k*k%95+32:k+32for k in range(95,0,-1)}) for s in ['','pub','pull!','M>>M','49','64','Hello, World!']]
['', 'HC0', 'HC33!', '>MM>', '4%', '64', 'He33o,\x7f9or3d!']
```

Comment: Welcome! Nice first post. You can remove the space between `32` and `for`.

Comment: ...also, [here](https://tio.run/##HYpBDsIgFAXXegpcmA@KLmy7gERu0Bu4oRG0ASmB78IYz47QzUze5MUPPpfQFXu9Fa9f012TLPMZkw7ZazT06w5uL4Zjd5Guwi6JODIHUg8PQ8XAfqy0iCZj6xSAQ3xPK73fVY9KjVW9ACa3m5jmgLTdOYGTAk7suhgr5Q8) is a link to an online interpreter test suite.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 80 bytes

```python
lambda s:''.join([chr(i+32)for i in range(95)if i*i%95==ord(c)-32][0]for c in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYSl1dLys/M08jOjmjSCNT29hIMy2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw9JUMzNNIVMrU9XS1NY2vyhFI1lT19goNtogFqQyGaSyWPN/QVFmXolCmoa6uiYXnF1QmoTKzclRRBbwtbPzReabWAJ5/wE)

Throws IndexError if no root exists.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
c@H+LÇ²%95+HÃbX
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/P9nBQ9vncPuhTaqWptoeh5uTIv7/VyooTVICAA)

Saved a byte by looking at the 05AB1E answer (using `L` = 100 instead of `95`). Now Japt is the shortest, a quite rare occurance :-D

#### Explanation

```
 c@ H+LÇ   ²  %95+HÃ bX
UcX{H+LoZ{Zp2 %95+H} bX}   Ungolfed
                           Implicit: U = input string, H = 32, L = 100
UcX{                   }   Map each charcode X in the input to the following:
      Lo                     Create the array [0, 1, ..., 98, 99]
        Z{         }         and map each item Z to
          Zp2                  Z ** 2
              %95              mod 95
                 +H            plus 32.
                     bX      Find the first index of X in this array. This gives the
                             smallest square root (mod 95) of (X - 32).
    H+                       Add 32 to map this back into the printable range.
                           Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>18</s> <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
95Ḷ²%95+32żØṖFyO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/S9OGObYc2qVqaahsbHd1zeMbDndPcKv3/H25/1LQm8v//aHV1HQX1gtIkCJWTowhi@NrZ@YJoE0sQaWYCIj2ABubrKITnF@WkKEI1KYA0xgIA) (comes with test-suite footer)

Saved 2 bytes by doing a complete rewrite. <s>Also the first time I've found use for `}`.</s>

#### Explanation

The code first calculates all square characters, and then maps them to their respective square roots.

```
95Ḷ²%95+32żØṖFyO    Main link. Argument: S (string)
95                    Take 95.
  Ḷ                   Get the array [0, 1, ..., 94].
   ²                  Square each to get [0, 1, ..., 8836].
    %95               Get each square modulo 95 to get [0, 1, ..., 1].
       +32            Add 32 to get [32, 33, ..., 33].
           ØṖ         Get the list of printables [" ", "!", ..., "~"].
          ż           Interleave with printables to get [[32, " "], ..., [33, "~"]].
             F        Flatten the mapping to [32, " ", ..., 33, "~"].
               O      Get the code point of each character in input.
              y       Map the code points to the correct output characters using the map.
```

Comment: `95Ḷ²%95+32iÐ€O+31Ọ` is basically what my Japt answer does, though your solution is two bytes shorter...

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 94 bytes

```
(R[x_]:=Min@Select[Range@45,Mod[#^2,95]==x&];FromCharacterCode[R/@(ToCharacterCode@#-32)+32])&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvtfIyi6Ij7WytY3M88hODUnNbkkOigxLz3VwcRUxzc/JVo5zkjH0jTW1rZCLdbarSg/1zkjsSgxuSS1yDk/JTU6SN9BIyQfRcxBWdfYSFPb2ChWU@1/QFFmXomCQ5qCg1JBaZLSfwA)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, 82 bytes

*Collaborated with @ETHproductions*

```
s=>s.map(x=>(g=z=>z*z%95==x.charCodeAt(0)-32?String.fromCharCode(z+32):g(z+1))(0))
```

*Input and output are in the form of a char array.*

#### Test snippet

```js
var f=s=>s.map(x=>(g=z=>z*z%95==x.charCodeAt(0)-32?String.fromCharCode(z+32):g(z+1))(0))

console.log(f([...""]));
console.log(f([..."pub"]));
console.log(f([..."pull!"]));
console.log(f([..."M>>M"]));
console.log(f([..."49"]));
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

```
vтLn95%žQykk33+ç?
```

The algorithm is very similar to the Jelly and Japt answer (Had something else before but that only got me to 19 bytes)

#### Explanation

```
vтLn95%žQykk33+ç?
v                 # For each character of the input...
 тL                # Push [1..100]
   n               # Square every element of the list
    95%            # And take it modulo 95
       žQyk        # Push the index of the current character in the printable ascii range
           k       # Push the index of that in the list created earlier
            33+    # Add 33 to the result
               ç   # And convert it back to a character
                ?  # Print the character
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/7GKTT56lqerRfYGV2dnGxtqHl9v//19QmgQA)

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica 82 Bytes

```
FromCharacterCode[Solve[x^2==#,Modulus->95][[1,1,2]]+32&/@(ToCharacterCode@#-32)]&
```

Using Solve's ability to do modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 65 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.chars.map{|c|((0..94).find{_1**2%95+32==c.ord}+32).chr}*""}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3HXXtiquL9ZIzEouK9XITC6prkms0NAz09CxNNPXSMvNSquMNtbSMVC1NtY2NbG2T9fKLUmqBTE2glqJaLSWlWohBqwoU3KKVCkqTlGIhAgsWQGgA)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 60 bytes

```
FromCharacterCode[PowerMod[ToCharacterCode@#-32,1/2,95]+32]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a string as input and returns a string as output. Errors on invalid input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 53 bytes

```
{[~] .comb.map({32+first *²%95==.ord-32,^95})».chr}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OrouVkEvOT83SS83sUCj2thIOy2zqLhEQevQJlVLU1tbvfyiFF1jI504S9NazUO79ZIzimr/WysUJ1YqKKnEK9jaKVSnKajE1yoppOUXKdTYFJQmKRSU5uQoKphY2ukoqPva2fmqW/8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>59</s> 55 bytes

```factor
[ [ 32 - 95 iota [ sq 95 mod = ] with find 32 + ] map ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY29DsIwEIP3PMWRFcHAz1AQXRFDWRBT1eFIrxA1TdPkKoQQzx7SLrY/y5IbVNz7eL9drucDdMivtUf7pDBnaMlbMhBoGMmq1DpPzB/ntWU4CvEVUgrpxsesxiySF3leJNtlUvxiCSVsN7CCbA@6Z0wYhgm6voYTVPDW6abRtp5my1R06KCKkwZG1a5BGUIf/w)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 120 bytes

```go
func f(s[]rune)[]rune{
for i:=range s{for k:=0;k<95;k++{r:=rune(k*k%95+32)
if r==s[i]{s[i]=rune(k+32)
break}}}
return s}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVBLTsMwFBRbn-I1IsgmAVWkRU1KwgKkdkEk2NBFGylJG1chqVPsBCFFPgmbColDcBQ4Dc6HTb2Yefab5xm9j89tcfjeR-ss2iawi1KG0t2-4OWlRnel9lWV9GLy804rtgaKxTLgFUtIRzWiBYfUcXnE1LCom2vmuMNpdmOPp5lh1Fw1lRJn55lujw3riqCUAnddsUyDuoG-37ZinkSZlBLxpKw4AyE7_9-TWRugiYdJjd4iDjG40DxiAaLkKduSjur_2faGKe6yYkEIkUgI4bjLoJeGoRnuq7jFPB8o9j3PVzSyFVyPFMyTPC9MWBQ83yiBBoNT_YwYQ2s0sR3v7n724D89L4Iwfsn3r5UmUVEURw7zu2GLltU4eL7vNQ66goptEpqyZHNU36oTym674LjQ71cIqNGj-rekWAt1Ea6Y60FXAADWBVkxzVQ6tVczxl1BTBWpYSRRv8_DoeM_)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 56 bytes

```javascript
s=>Buffer(s).map(x=>(g=y=>y*y%95+32-x?g(++y):y+32)``)+``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3fCsIgHEZfxS4CzeZFf6ANNAi63BNU8LNNZcNUZov59Ca7@Q7fzTmj/MnYTUP4Vs73KmueIxe3WWs14UjYRwa8cIENT1ykXdrWZ3o8VMvVYEoTaVJ5BIBQgNx5F71VzHqDHwB7CPN7XWs3ha0QbcGphteqLZ3IguzvrseXIuAIIaC6VAkb/eDg6YDkPw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 33 bytes

```
FiA*a YyAE((SQ,h)%95+32@?i)+32 Cy
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJGaUEqYSBZeUFFKChTUSxoKSU5NSszMkA/aSkrMzIgQ3kiLCIiLCIiLCJwdWIiXQ==)

---

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 37 bytes

```
FiA*a-32 YyAE((SQ_%95=i)FI,h)@0+32 Cy
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJGaUEqYS0zMiBZeUFFKChTUV8lOTU9aSlGSSxoKUAwKzMyIEN5IiwiIiwiIiwicHViIl0=)